# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, referenceerror

How come this code throws an

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

when it was OK before?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabs > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
  $('#featuredvid > ul').tabs();
});
```

Results in tabs don't close anymore.

jQuery is referenced in the header:

```html
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl') ?>/js/sprinkle.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl') ?>/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl') ?>/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl') ?>/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script> Take this on top

Comment: In my case, the JQuery was on footer section, so the JS function was called first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268881/referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 816):

You should put the references to the jquery scripts first.

```html
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/sprinkle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just to be sure this is clear: you cannot put the script reference to jquery-ui before the jquery script itself. That's what fixed the problem to me: first jquery-x.x.x.min.js, then jquery-ui-xxxxxx.js.

Comment: 2 years later, still the answer is not "ticked" )
[**This articles**](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/02/referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined.html) describes this one and 4 more common cases when this error occurs.

Comment: can you give step by step solution, I'm new to to this

Answer (score 300):

You are calling the ready function before the jQuery JavaScript is included. Reference jQuery first.

Comment: @RamSharma Actually, this is the right answer. You don't need anything else to solve the issue.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Answer (score 176):

This is what solved it for me.  Originally I went to Google and copied and pasted their suggested snippet for jQuery on their CDN page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The snippet does not include the `HTTP:` or `HTTPS:` in the `src` attribute but my browser, FireFox, needed it so I changed it to:
edit: this worked for me with Google Chrome as well

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Then* it worked.

Answer (score 50):

If your custom script is loaded before the jQuery plugin is loaded to the browser then this type of problem may occur. So, always keep your own JavaScript or jQuery code after calling the jQuery plugin so the solution for this is :

First add the link to the jQuery file hosted at GoogleApis or a local jQuery file that you will download from http://jquery.com/download/ and host on your server:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or any plugin for jQuery. Then put your custom script file link or code:

```
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 44):

In my case I was putting my `.js` file before the jQuery script link, putting the `.js` file after jQuery script link solved my issue.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="exponential.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 32):

Add the library before you start the script.You can add any of these following **CDN** to start it.

**Google:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Microsoft**

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Jquery**

If you want any other Jquery cdn version check this [link](https://jquery.com/download/).

After this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    //your stuff
});
or
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your stuff
});    
</script>
```

**Wordpress:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery;
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     //your stuff
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 30):

Okay, my problem was different - it was **Document Security** model in **Chrome**.

Looking at the answers here, it was obvious that I was somehow not loading my jquery files before calling the `$(document).ready()` etc. functions. However, they were all in the correct positions.

In my case, this was because I was accessing the content over a secure HTTPS connection, whereas the page was trying to download the CDN hosted data from google, etc. The solution was to store them locally and then include then directly rather than from the CDN each time.

*Edit*: The other way of doing this is to link to all the CDN-hosted stuff as https:// rather than http:// - then the model doesn't complain.

Answer (score 21):

Add jQuery library before your script which uses $ or jQuery so that $ can be identified in scripts.
remove tag script on head and put end bady

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

then first write script in file js add

```
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function(){  });
```

Comment: **Danger**: The version of jQuery used here has known security issues and is unsupported. Get the latest version from the jQuery website.

Answer (score 20):

You are calling the `ready()` function before the jQuery JavaScript is included. Reference jQuery first.

If you're in ASP.NET MVC, you can specify when your JS code should be rendered, by doing this:

**1,** In your `page.cshtml` wrap your `<script>` tag into a section, and give it a name, the common name to use is 'scripts':

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        // JS code...
    </script>
}
```

**2,** In your `_Layout.cshtml` page add `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`, make sure to put it after you reference the Jquery source, this will make your JS code render later than the Jquery.

Answer (score 19):

I had the exact same problem and none of these solutions above helped.
however, I just linked the `.css` files after the `.js` files and the problem miraculously disappeared. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 19):

If it's in wordpress, might be needed to change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

or add

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

before

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 16):

In my case I had this referenceError as the order of script calls was wrong. Solved that by changing the order:

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 16):

I wanted to try to make my script **asynchronous**. Then I forgot about it and when I went live the [custom].js file only loaded 50% of the time before the jQuery.js.

So I changed

```
<script async src="js/script.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem , and I solved by putting jQuery at the top of all javascript codes I have in my code.

Something like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/create.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/tween.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope can help some one in future.

Answer (score 11):

**put latest jquery cdn on top of your main html page**

*Like If your main html page is **index.html***

**place jquery cdn on top of this page like this**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("h2").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This will hide me</h2>


<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was a typo, I forgot a backslash and was referencing the source incorrectly.

Before `src="/scripts/jquery.js"`

After    `src="scripts/jquery.js"`

Answer (score 8):

Include the `jQuery` CDN (or `jQuery` ref) in the index file first. before including your JS file to ensure we are accessing the `jQuery`.
following lines worked for me

Can get a clear idea about this by referring to the following link
reference site:

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-fix-dollar-is-not-defined-error-in-jquery.php

> **Answer: Execute Code after jQuery Library has Loaded**
> The most common reason behind the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" is executing the jQuery code before the jQuery library file has loaded. Therefore make sure that you're executing the jQuery code only after jQuery library file has finished loading.

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing this in .Net and have the script file referenced properly and you jQuery looks fine, make sure that your users have access to the script file. The project I was working on (a coworker) had their web.config denying access to anonymous users. The page I was working on was accessible to anonymous users therefore they didn't have access to the script file. Dropped the following into the web.config and all was right in the world:

```
  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 5):

The source file `jquery-1.2.6.min.js` is not called the jQuery command `$()` is executed earlier than `<..src='jquery-1.2.6.min.js'>`.

Please run `<.. src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js..">` at first and make sure the src path is right, then execute jquery command

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me before.

The reason was that I'm connecting android to a webview with a JS. And I sent a parameter without quotes.

```
js.sayHello(hello);
```

and when I changed it to

```
js.sayHello('hello');
```

it worked.

Comment: I've no idea what parameter without quotes means... it sounds like you had a reference error.

Comment: I had a problem in Freemarker and the reason was absence of single quotes, so the value was treated not like a string, but as a variable

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue.  My test server was working fine with  "http". However it failed in production which had SSL.

Thus in production, I added "HTPPS" instead of "HTTP" and in test, i kept as it is  "HTTP".

### Test:

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false );

wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
```

### Production:

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false );

wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Hope this will help someone who is working on wordpress.

Answer (score 5):

The error will occur in the following two scenarios as well.

1. @section scripts element is missing from the HTML file
2. Error in accessing DOM elements. For example accessing of DOM element is mentioned as $("js-toggle") instead of $(".js-toggle"). Actually the period is missing

So 3 things to be followed - check required scripts are added, check if it is added in the required order and third syntax errors in your Java Script.

Answer (score 4):

Your JavaScript file is missing so this error occurred. Just add the JavaScript file inside the `<head>` tag. See the example:

```
<script src="js/sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or add the following code in  tag :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case i forgot to include this :

```
 <script src ="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
```

Earlier I was including just jquery-mobile which was causing this error.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the script tag to point to the right content and changed the script order to be the right one in the editor. But totally forgot to save the change.

Answer (score 3):

Doh! I had mixed quotes in my  tags that caused the jquery reference to break.  Doing an inspect in Chrome allowed me to see that the file wasn't properly linked.

Answer (score 3):

You have not referenced a jQuery library.

You'll need to include a line similar to this in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it was because I was missing a closing > on a style sheet link.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="local_xxx.js"></script>
```

I have similar issue, and you know what, it's because of **network is disconnected** when I test in android device webview and I don't realize it, and the local js no problem to load because it doesn't need network. It seems ridiculous but it waste my ~1 hour to figure out it.

Answer (score 2):

if you are laraveling that error comes  on in blade files when you forgot to surround the code with :

```
@section('section name')
```

.......

```
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange enough, my problem was coming from PHP.

A REST API call was failing, and it was breaking the loading of the libraries afterwards. Since failure was from the REST call, it was not giving me a php compile error.

Keep this as an option also, if loading jquery seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, when I was browsing internet through my mobile hotspot. it was also compressing images and added the following script at the bottom of body tag

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
bmi_SafeAddOnload(bmi_load,"bmi_orig_img");//-->
</script>
```

When I connected to proper wifi connection, all seems to work find for me. Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen, if there is network issue. Which means, that even though the " jquery scripts " are in place, and are included prior to usage, since the jquery-scripts are not accessible, at the time of loading the page, hence the definitions to the "$" are treated as "undefined references".

**FOR TEST/DEBUG PURPOSES ::** You can try to access the "jquery-script" url on browser. If it is accessible, your page, should load properly, else it will show the said error (or other script relevant errors). Example - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js should be accessible, on the browser (or browser context stances).

I had similar problem, in which I was able to load the html-page (using scripts) in my windows-host-browser, but was not able to load in vm-ubuntu. Solving the network issue, got the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the worst case:

Everything seemed perfect. After spending a couple of hours I realized that the jquery file which is added in the correct position was actually a file with empty content!

Comment: That is like common sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call jquery first and then call javascript,as java script depends on jquery, so it should be loaded before javascript and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Root problem is a `ReferenceError`.  [MDN indicates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) that a `try`/`catch` block is the proper tool for the job. In my case, I was getting uncaught reference error for a payment sdk/library. The below works for me.

```
try {
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_---------');
} catch (e) {
    stripe = null;
}

if(stripe){
  //we are good to go now
}
```

Obviously the fix is to load whatever SDK/library, e.g. jQuery, prior to calling its methods but the `try`/`catch` does keep your shared JavaScript from barfing up errors in case you run that shared script on a page that doesn't load whatever library you use on a subset of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when tried to run different web-socket samples.

When pointing browser to '*http://localhost:8080/*' I got this error, but pointing exactly to '*http://localhost:8080/index.html*' gave no error since in 'index.html' all was fully ok - jquery was included before using $..

Somehow autoforwarding to index.html not fully worked

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the problem has been solved after installing Windows Server Role Service 'Static Content'. ( OS : Windows Server 2008 R2 )

How to install the 'Static Content' Server Role Service :

- ( Assuming that the 'Web Server' Role is already installed ) > Run Server Manager > Click 'Roles' in left pane > click 'Add Role Services' in the 'Web Server' area in right pane > select 'Static Content' under 'Web Server / Common HTTP Features' > Click 'Next' > ...

Answer (score -2):

Bitten by this once again, missing library source links. 
[Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)
[Similar link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946616/javascript-uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined-uncaught-referenceerr)

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('cadmin/survey/chart_survey_assisten'); ?>", function (json) { 
                    var acctregs = new Morris.Donut({
                                // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
                                element: 'hadir-chart-bar-assisten',
                                // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
                                // the chart.
                                data: json,
                                xkey: 'label',
                                ykeys: ['value'],
                                labels: ['Nilai'],
                                barRatio: 0.4,
                                xLabelAngle: 35,
                                hideHover: 'auto',
                                resize: true
                            });
                });
           });
```