# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in a jquery function

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I had been getting this message when I use a JavaScript function for the `onchange` event of a select option.

The function is:

```
<script type="text/javasript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function desigchanged()
{
    
    $.get('jqueryphp.php?desig=wr',update);
}
function update(res)
{
    $('#inpt4').html(res);
}
</script>


<select id="inpt3" name ="designatn" onChange="desigchanged();">
            <option value="pm" selected>project manager</option>
            <option value="wr">worker</option>
            </select><BR><BR>
            <label><font id="fnm">Gender</font></label>
            <label><font id="fnm3">Male</font></label>
            <input name="gender" type="radio" id="inpt11" value="Male" />
            <label><font id="fnm4">Female</font></label>
            <input name="gender" type="radio" id="inpt22" value="Female" /><BR><BR>
            <label><font id="fnm">Works Under</font></label>
            <select name="wrkundr" id="inpt4">
            </select>
```

The jQuery file is included properly.
Please someone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's because of the typo:

```
type="text/javasript"
```

Note the missing "c" in "script". Browsers won't execute a script tag if its `type` attribute hasn't been defined correctly.

Comment: It's all the browsers according to my tests - if the type is defined but not correct, it won't be executed. This is good because you can place templates in `text/html` or whatever. Here's my test http://jsfiddle.net/s5rnv/

Comment: @Esailija: Thanks; I usually omit it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

But you may also be [facing this problem](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined) (absolute/relative paths).

And

You also have a typo for `javascript`

**Original:**

[have you done this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075349/728863)

> You should put the references to the jquery scripts first.

Or

[This?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075345/728863)

> Maybe you are calling the ready function before the JQuery Javascript is included?

Comment: As can be seen in his snippet, he's including jQuery at the top and he's not using `ready`.

Comment: @pimvdb yeh, I just wanted to make sure that its the same way he is executing too. as some ppl cut/paste codes and make it cleaner here to make it look good :P ... btw I edited my post too