# "ReferenceError: mage is not defined" error during website loading after migrating Magento website from another system

Tags: javascript, magento-1.7

> mage is not defined
>
> translate is not defined
>
> decorateList is not defined
>
> Varien is not defined

This is what i get when i try to open Magento website.
I do not know what happened, but my site does not load Cs and JavaScript pages.
Please help if someone has a solution.

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the JavaScript files that define the above variables?

Comment: @ppoliani thanks for reply i was loading my magento website when i got this error..with this my magento website look plain without any css..and when i try to open another page like my wishlist i got server cant open this file error

Comment: please help if you got issue resolved, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Weird errors when loading Magento page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377140/weird-errors-when-loading-magento-page)

I solved this with the solution proposed by systematical in his comment: copy over all the `<action method="addJs">` lines from 
*app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml* to *app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout/page.xml*