# jQuery code doesn't work

Tags: jquery, runtime-error

I'm beginer at jQuery.
I tried to do easy example but this doesn't work.
Show some **errors:**

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` => `$(document).ready(function() {`

`Failed to load resource`

I guess that I missed something but can't understand what it is.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><head> <title>jQuery goes to DOM-ville</title>
        <style>
            #change_me {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 400px;
            font: 24px arial;}

            #move_up #move_down #color #disappear {
            padding: 5px;}
        </style>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="move_up">Move Up</button>
        <button id="move_down">Move Down</button>
        <button id="color">Change Color</button>
        <button id="disappear">Disappear/Re-appear</button>
        <div id="change_me">Make Me Do Stuff!</div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#move_up").click( function() {
                        $("#change_me").animate({top:30},200);
                });//end move_up
                $("#move_down").click( function() {
                    $("#change_me").animate({top:500},2000);
                });//end move_down
                $("#color").click( function() {
                    $("#change_me").css("color", "purple");
                });//end color
                $("#disappear").click( function() {
                    $("#change_me").toggle("slow");
                });//end disappear
            });//end doc ready
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Question:**

- How to solve this trouble?

Comment: are you sure jquery is at correct path - `scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js`

Comment: Does your jquery script file actually exist at scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js?

Comment: Check if `scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js` is a valid URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined

Try this.

Comment: Replace this `<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>` with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` and see if you are still getting any errors??

Comment: @Palash Mondal All work perfect! But why this happened and how this changes improve this?

Comment: Just make sure your local jquery file _(jquery-1.6.2.min.js)_ is at correct path and everything will work perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check the `view page source` from browser by right click and check jquery file is attached

2) or other way check from browser's `console` panel that file is attached

3) it also occurs when you haven't mentioned the right path in the `src` attribute