# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-io

I have this code in `jQuery`: (the file name is javascript.js ...I was using JavaScript before...)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#readFile").click(function() {
    $.get('test.txt', function(data) {
      $("#bottom_pane_options").html(data); // #bottom_pane_options is the div I want the data to go
    }, 'text');
 });
});
```

...and this in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Culminating</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJnj2nWoM86eU8Bq2G4lSNz3udIkZT4YY&sensor=false">
    </script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        function initialize()
        {
        var mapProp = {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(50.569283,-84.378433),
          zoom:5,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
          };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="googleMap"></div>
        <div id="right_pane_results">hi</div>
        <div id="bottom_pane_options">
            <button id="readFile">Read File</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I check the console, I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError` saying that `$` is not defined on the first line.  I'm assuming that it is referring to the first character on the first line.  I got this code from a website and I'm new to `jQuery` so I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should include the jQuery first

Comment: Try to add your own code script at end of your html content, before your closing </body> tag to avoid this like `$ is not defined` Error's. And add other pre-defined Jquery or some other library in top <head> tag. your order should be - `<head> <script scr="jquery.js"></script> </head>` and inside the body `<body> <script src="myscript.js"></script> </body>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Change the order you're including your scripts (jQuery first):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_APIKEY&sensor=false">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer got rid of the problem.  But now I am getting an error saying that I am missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  I know I need to add `Allow-Control-Access-Origin: *` but I'm not sure **where** to put it.

Answer (score 7):

Include the jQuery file first:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJnj2nWoM86eU8Bq2G4lSNz3udIkZT4YY&sensor=false">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Scripts are loaded in the order you have defined them in the HTML.

Therefore if you first load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
```

without loading jQuery first, then `$ is not defined`.

You need to first load jQuery so that you can use it.

I would also recommend placing your scripts at the bottom of your HTML for performance reasons.

Comment: ...loaded and interpreted in order. the OP's assumption seems to be that they are interpreted only after all of them are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The MVC 5 stock install puts javascript references in the _Layout.cshtml file that is shared in all pages. So the javascript files were below the main content and document.ready function where all my $'s were.

BOTTOM PART OF _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

I moved them above the 
            @RenderBody() and all was fine.

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```