# Error on Ajax -> $.ajax -> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have problem with this block of ajax code, this function is triggered by onChange event on combobox,

```
function showDistr()
{
 idstate = document.getElementById("statepar").value;
 $.ajax({
   url:'load_distr.php/?id="+idstate +"',
   success: function(response) {
     $('#dist').html(response);
   },
   dataType:"html"
   });
  return false;
}
```

this is the combobox,

```
<select class="form-control" id="statepar" onChange="showDistr()" style=\"WIDTH: 250px; HEIGHT: 22px\" >
```

it comes error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" on $.ajax({

anyone give me suggestion about this?

thank you

Comment: **jQuery** is not included..

Comment: use jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not include jQuery library, before first use of `$`.

Refer: [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190580/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-error-in-jquery)

Comment: thank you man, i misplaced the location of jquery,

Answer (score -1):

Include jquery.js library file in project.

[jquery-2.1.4.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)

Comment: thank you man, i misplaced the location of jquery,

Answer (score -1):

Include jQuery script file to your code

```
<!-- include jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you man, i misplaced the location of jquery,