# Change button color if HTML.DropDownListFor changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

EDIT: Turns out I needed to move the jquery reference in the _Layout file above @RenderBody() like they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33460229/11788388)

I'm trying to "activate" my submission button when the data in the dropdown menus meet my requirements. So when the data in the first dropdown stops matching the data in the second one, the submit button should change from grey to orange.

Included is the javascript I tried to make this happen, but according to the Visual Studios debugger, the javascript hasn't even been touched. I'm new to javascript, and based on the research I've done, I can't tell what's wrong.

Dropdowns:

```
 <tr>
   <td>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Starting, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Location))), htmlAttributes: new { @id = "start", @style = @"  width: 192px; height: 32px; border-radius: 2px; border: solid 1px #babcbe; background-color: #ffffff;" })
    </td>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Endpoint, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Location))), htmlAttributes: new { @id = "end", @style = @"  width: 192px; height: 32px; border-radius: 2px; border: solid 1px #babcbe; background-color: #ffffff;" })
   </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#start").change(function() {
         var selectedStart = $("#start option:selected").val();
         var selectedEnd = $("#end option:selected").val();

         if (selectedStart != selectedEnd) {
             $("#toNext").css("background-color", "#f06424");
         } else {
             $("#toNext").css("background-color", "grey");
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

Button at the end

```
<button class="btn" id="toNext" input type="submit">Next</button>
```

Comment: Your .js file looks right to me... personally I use the browser to debug .js code, so I don't know much about Vs debugger. There might be an error on your script, you can hit F12 on your favorite browser and check if there are any error on the page...