# HTML loaded into Webview as data string, jQuery is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webview, google-chrome-app

In an attempt to skirt the following issues, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321638, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=452685, and to make my Chrome packaged app work on Chrome 57+, I am loading an HTML page into the WebView as a data string, using `FileReader()` and the `readAsDataURL()` method.

The HTML file is your standard affair, containing references to external CSS and JS files.

Towards the bottom of the page, my JS scripts are called, again, pretty typical stuff, using `<script src="../../shared/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` for example. (Please ignore the terrible pathing).

Now, it seems like the HTML file is loaded and parsed correctly, but I get the age old error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Checking the erroneous line, it is in an inline (again, please don't shoot me) script that is after the jQuery script tag.

Are there any hidden caveats with loading HTML as a data string, specifically into a WebView?

Comment: could you type `jQuery` into console, is it also undefined?

Comment: typing `jQuery` comes back as undefined, but that's because I'm not using `jQuery`, I'm using `$`. I can make such calls as `$('#my-div');` and get a result back.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined). You're encountering an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.` maybe because you are calling the ready function before the jQuery JavaScript is included. You should put the references to the jQuery scripts first.

Here's another reference:

- [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190580/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-error-in-jquery)
- [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050581/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Ah see, normally you would be correct, but in this case, the data encoded HTML file actually has `<script>` tags that load jQuery (a local copy of the library) before a block of javascript in the HTML page. Hence my question. If loaded in an `<iframe>` for example, the HTML is fine, and jQuery is loaded as it should be, before my block of script.