# Using tabs in textareas? Why does this not work?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, textarea

I know that many people have asked about tabs and textareas before, and I've seen many good answers, including the code shown below, but for some reason it has no effect on my webpage at all.

```
$(document).delegate('#textbox', 'keydown', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if (keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var start = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
    var end = $(this).get(0).selectionEnd;


    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start)
                + "\t"
                + $(this).val().substring(end));


    $(this).get(0).selectionStart =
    $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = start + 1;
  }
});
```

The textarea is the only element on my page at the moment, could that be affecting it? 
All JS files are linked correctly with my page, and JS is enabled on my browser!
Any feedback would be gratefully received!

Comment: The code is working for me mate. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfYXf/)

Comment: Hmmm. weird. I'm pretty sure I've linked my jquery correctly. Maybe not...  it's just this, right?  `<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`

Comment: No mate, I don't see a problem with that too. Your problem could be somewhere else. Any errors in the console?

Comment: I just looked and it gave me this ... `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Is the `script` tag for jQuery present in the code before the `script` in the question? Check if any of the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined) SO thread helps.

Comment: Sure, go for it! I'll accept it when you do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code given in the question works fine (as can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfYXf/)).

The `script` tag to add jQuery also seems to be fine. But it must be present above the `script` provided in the question. This is because jQuery is needed for its execution.