# Adobe Edge Preloader JQuery/$ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

I've been working with Adobe Edge for some time now and I also want to use the Preloader to load data for my composition via AJAX. To achieve this I created the following code inside the Preloader>loading-Event. Which event is a bit of a Problem because there is no documentation at all for that, so I have not the slightest idea when it is fired.

```
// this little fella is fetching url-
// parameters and puts them in a var called GET
(function () {
    window.GET = {};
    var s = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    if (!s.length) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var parts = s[i].split('=');
        window.GET[unescape(parts[0])] = unescape(parts[1]);
    }
}())

var playlist = GET["l"],
    playlistLoadSuccessHandler = function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
    };

$.ajax({
    url: playlist,
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: playlistLoadSuccessHandler
});
```

So and all I'm getting is this: **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Has anyone a little more experience in Adobe Edge than me and knows what my mistake is here?

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery?

Comment: it should be implemented by the edge runtime by the time my code is executed. if I print "this" inb4 my code i can see that $ is present and properly filled with jquery.

Comment: If jQuery IS loaded, try jQuery.ajax({ as you may not have defined $

Comment: and i read several examples on using jquery in the preloader, which all referenced - as usual - jquery with $

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Not to familiar with Adobe-Edge

Comment: already tried that and it brings the same error only with $ replaced by jQuery :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined  Are you calling in the jQuery scripts in first?

Comment: thank you! this might be the solution. i checked the load-timeline of the scripts and indeed is edgePreload.js ahead of jquery.js
i will try to solve this and post my solution ASAP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that's the way Edge works. jQuery is loaded **after** the preloader has done its work. I will try to get around without jQuery and use good 'ol native JS until Adobe shows some mercy and fixes this.