# $ is not defined when calling $.holdReady(true)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load scripts on web page in the following order:

```
<head>
 ...
<script src="/file1.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>$.holdReady(true);</script>
<script src="/file2.js"></script>

...
</head>
```

And **sometimes** I receive an error **"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"** in the line `<script>$.holdReady(true);</script>` but file1.js and jquery-1.7.2.min.js are loaded successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: usually you need to use a selector eg. $(".myclass").holdready(true);

Comment: @user2310289 - that's not correct. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: What's in `file1.js`? Anything referencing `$` ?

Comment: Example on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/ : $.holdReady( true );

Comment: @ahren: there is no references to $ in file1.js

Comment: Any `asnyc` or `defer` attributes on the jQuery `script` tag?

Comment: Can you try using 'jQuery' instead of '$'? Also, no 404 in the console? Have you checked the contents of the jQuery file?

Comment: I would guess there is something wrong with jquery file you have if you are 100% sure it is being loaded properly

Comment: @foiseworth: when I'm trying to open content of jQuery file I see the following message in firebug network tab: "Reload the page to get source for: https://domain/jquery-1.7.2.min.js". It seems something wrong with jQuery file loading...

Comment: @foiseworth: http status code fo jquery file "200 OK"

Comment: What happens when you open the jquery file directly via its URL?

Comment: @foiseworth: I see "Content Encoding Error.
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

Comment: Response headers: Accept-Ranges bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... *
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 94840
Content-Type application/x-javascript
Date Mon, 11 Nov 2013 09:13:00 GMT
Etag "2f2f7f4048d9ce1:0"
Last-Modified Mon, 04 Nov 2013 10:25:58 GMT
Vary Accept-Encoding

Comment: @Andrei - There's your problem. For some reason, your copy of jQuery is being served incorrectly by the server. Either have a look at the server's settings, or try using a third party CDN (e.g. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery).

Comment: @Andrei good practise to specify <script type="text/javascript" > instead of plain <script> tag. Maybe this could be the problem, since Olly says its serving you the page incorrectly

Comment: @Barun HTML5 makes the `type="text/javascript"` the default and hence optional (because browsers did so anyway since back to Netscape times)

Answer (score 0):

As @foiseworth says you can try to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

You ca also try something like this:

```
(function($){
    $.holdReady(true);
})(jQuery);
```

Try to put the jQuery inclusion right after you open `head` tag and then `holdReady` right after jQuery and then your scripts if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reordering the imports this way. All imports first then the calling code.

```
<script src="/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/file1.js"></script>
<script src="/file2.js"></script>
<script>$.holdReady(true);</script>
```

My answer refers to this question on stackoverflow : [uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)