# Ajax Get request not working when fetching HttpResponse from Django views

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm experimenting a little bit with Django and Ajax. I want to make a simple view with a button that when someone clicks on it, the website alerts the data taken from another view in my `views.py`, which is an HttpResponse that says "foo". Currently, when I click on the button, nothing appears. I was wondering what has gone wrong here. My code is as follows:

In my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request): 
    return render(request,"ajax/index.html")

def test(request): 
    return HttpResponse("foo")
```

In my `index.html`:

```
<body> 
<div> hello world </div> 
<button class="btn"> click this </button>
</body>
<script> 

$(".btn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '//http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/',
        type: 'GET', 
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("something went wrong")
        }
    }); 
});

</script>
```

In my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from ajax import views as ajax_views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/',ajax_views.index,name="index),
    path('test/',ajax_views.test,name="test")  
]
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What if you use a `JsonResponse` (and pass an object)

Comment: It still doesn't work. I changed `return HttpResponse("foo")` to `return JsonResponse({"foo":"bar"})`, but nothing appears when I clicked on the button. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: @DoNguyenTung: perhaps you should take a look at the browser console, and see if it logs a warning/error when you fire the AJAX call (Ctrl+Shift+K in FF). Furthermore take a look to the server log to see if it receives a GET request.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for the suggestion. Currently, when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/`, the browser (Chrome) console displays an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):6`. Meanwhile, the server log only has `[12/Aug/2020 23:02:52] "GET /index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 406`. So I suppose there is a problem with how the Ajax is written?

Comment: Update: Follow the advice of this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268881/referenceerror-is-not-defined. I add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` before the script in which I use ajax. Good thing is that the GET request is sent; however, it alerts "Something went wrong", which means the request is not successfully processed.

Comment: Update #2: I get the Ajax working by fixing the URL from `url: '//http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/'` to `url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/'` . Thank you @WillemVanOnsem for helping me out with this!