# Javascript - Duplicate Field input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to duplicate a field input like [this in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3h54k9cs/1/)

But when I save the below in a html file, it is not working.

Can someone please assist?

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
$(function() { // <== Doc Ready
  $("#email").change(function() { // When email is changed
    $('#mail').val(this.value); // copy it over to mail
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to load jquery in order for this to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268881/referenceerror-is-not-defined) (Though don't just copy that answer. Get the latest version of jQuery.)

Comment: Don't edit the question in such a way that it obscures the problem the OP is having. Instead post an answer indicating how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is working as expected.

The only issue with your code was the jQuery was not loaded to the snippet.

But instead of `change`, if you use `keyup` or `input`, you could see the changes right on time

Change will be triggered only when you focus away from your input.

```js
$(function() { // <== Doc Ready
  $("#email").on('keyup', function() { // When email is changed
    $('#mail').val(this.value); // copy it over to mail
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
```

Comment: You're missing the main problem, which is that the OP has not loaded jquery. Also, [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) is more responsive than `keyup`

Comment: @pilchard, Agreed. I suggested a way to improve.

Comment: But you didn't answer the main question. It's not working as expected **because they haven't loaded jquery**

Answer (score 0):

This code will run for sure.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#email').keyup(function(e){
    $('#mail').val(e.target.value);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />           
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail"/>
```