# Add readonly to input fields in jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, readonly, attr, prop

I have problems adding `readonly` to some input fields.

I have this code in the `<head>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#powermail_field_ordreid').prop('readonly', true);
    $('#powermail_field_destination').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

And then I have these 2 out of 6 input fields, that I need to add the `readonly` on.

```
<div id="powermail_fieldwrap_9" class="powermail_fieldwrap powermail_fieldwrap_input powermail_fieldwrap_9 ">
    <label class="powermail_label" for="powermail_field_ordreid"> Ordre id </label>
    <input id="powermail_field_ordreid" class="powermail_field powermail_input " type="text" value="0521104821">
</div>
<div id="powermail_fieldwrap_7" class="powermail_fieldwrap powermail_fieldwrap_input powermail_fieldwrap_7 ">
    <label class="powermail_label" for="powermail_field_destination"> Destination </label>
    <input id="powermail_field_destination" class="powermail_field powermail_input " type="text" value="Luxembourg">
</div>
```

I have tried `.attr()` and now im using `.prop()` because I'm using jQuery 1.10+, but I can still edit the input fields, what's wrong.

...EDIT...
Can see its works fine, on jsfiddel - so can someone tell me if its an other script that blok it here [http://wnf.dk/bestillingsform.html?tx_powermail_pi1[field][7]=Luxembourg](http://wnf.dk/bestillingsform.html?tx_powermail_pi1%5bfield%5d%5b7%5d=Luxembourg) the 2 first fields have the `readonly`add.

Comment: Your code works fine > http://jsfiddle.net/egQy3/

Comment: As @BenM says, this works fine. Have you checked the console for errors elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Are you using duplicate IDs??? Are these elements generated dynamically after DOM is ready? Why don't you set it by default directly on these inputs? BTW, you should try to replicate your issue on jsFiddle

Comment: Try `$('#powermail_field_ordreid').attr('readonly', '');`

Comment: thats funny, I can see its working in jsfiddle, but its not working in the main code. @A. Wolff yes i think so, about the generation.

Comment: i tried to repricate your problem on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zz8na/  the readonly is working fine there

Comment: plz. see edit in main question.

Comment: @Thomas, when navigating your site, the error console shows `$(...).responsiveimages is not a function`. Looks like you're missing a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web, console log: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

You should put the references to the jquery scripts first. [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Close, but apparently only the responsive images plugin is missing, not the whole jQuery.

Comment: Hi Frederic i edit the code for 30 min ago, to user2261516, so that worked to switch some of the JS files from footer to header, THX user 2261516

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#powermail_field_ordreid').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#powermail_field_destination').attr('readonly', true);
    });
</script>
```

it works for jQuery <1.9

jQuery 1.9+

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#powermail_field_ordreid').prop('readonly', true);
            $('#powermail_field_destination').prop('readonly', true);
        });
    </script>
```

you may look at http://jsfiddle.net/najibcse/M7rkB/

Comment: But OP is using `jQuery 1.10+`

Comment: What is the point of your answer? The questioner is already using your second code snippet.

Comment: I have used  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js for test and both attr & prop works for me. @Frédéric Hamidi please look at http://jsfiddle.net/najibcse/M7rkB/

Comment: @Najib U are not reading the question, and see/read what other have wrote.

Comment: @thomas-bog-petersen yap, for the time being I was testing in jsfiddle.