# Console Error with Ajax: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

i have a problem with a little script on my html page. It's just a function which should be called by an onclick method in an a tag. It dont works. Everytime i click on the link in the browser the console says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" and points on the third line of the code below.

```
<script>
    function del(urlToDelete) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlToDelete,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(results) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the code that you expect to define `$`?

Comment: `$.ajax()` is a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) function, the `$` being a shorthand for `jQuery` when writing code using it, so you'd need to load jQuery before that code will work. From the error message you haven't done that.

Comment: include jquery properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to include jquery library for that.Like this. You need to include this 1st, then write `$.ajax` to execute.

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the jQuery libraries have not been included within your project.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers use http version,which might not be allowed at production ,alternatively use:

```
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

or visit: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Errors : SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'ajax' and SCRIPT5008: SCRIPT5008: Invalid left-hand side in assignment can u tell me after pasting this library in my html file it is diplaying the above errors

Answer (score 0):

When pulling sample code from Bootstrap (and possibly others), it's likely the slim version. This doesn't include ajax. Pick "uncompressed" or "minified" from https://releases.jquery.com/jquery/.