# Minimal Example for dynamic HTML pages with Django and AJAX

Tags: python, html, ajax, django

I refer to the following posts:

- [Reload table data in Django without refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774138/reload-table-data-in-django-without-refreshing-the-page#)
- [Django dynamic HTML table refresh with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548863/django-dynamic-html-table-refresh-with-ajax#)

Despite the two post and nice answers, I am still struggling to construct a minimal working example for dynamic HTML pages resorting to Django and AJAX.

I have to following code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^get_more_tables', views.get_more_tables, name='get_more_tables')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question

def index(request):
    a = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'questions': a}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def get_more_tables(request):
    a = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'questions': a}
    return render(request, 'polls/get_more_tables.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<table id="_appendHere">
<tr><td> text </td></tr>

{% for a in questions %}
<tr><td>    {{ a.question_text }} </td></tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
</body>
</html>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
var append_increment = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{% url 'get_more_tables' %}",
        data: {'append_increment': append_increment}
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        $('#_appendHere').append(response);
        append_increment += 10;
    });
}, 1000)
```

**get_more_tables.html**

```
{% for a in questions %}
<tr><td>    {{ a.question_text }} </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I have the following issues:

- According to [Console Error with Ajax: ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273833/console-error-with-ajax-referenceerror-is-not-defined), I need to set up the js.file in the js-script. If I do not do that, I get the "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error. Why is that, in particular, as this is not necessary for the previous above mention posts?
- If I run http://localhost:8000/polls/, nothing happens. I was assuming that, when I use

  q2 = Question(question_text="What's up4?", pub_date=timezone.now())
  q2.save()

by python manage.py shell, the entire internal database should be shown. However, nothing is happening. When I refresh the site by hand, all entries are shown.

- The inspector console of Mozilla does not show any entry. The network console of Mozilla does show that /pools and the external js file is accessed. However, no continuous access in 1s intervals is shown (not sure if that should be the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is not valid, for a couple of reasons.

First, you put the script block outside the closing `</html>` tag. That means it's outside the document itself, and may not be read by the browser.

More importantly, you haven't got your code inside a proper script element. You have an opening tag, but you use that to reference the external jQuery library via the `src` attribute. You don't have a closing tag at all

You need to put the jQuery reference in its own element, and use proper opening and closing tags for your own script.

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
...
</table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var append_increment = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{% url 'get_more_tables' %}",
        data: {'append_increment': append_increment}
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        $('#_appendHere').append(response);
        append_increment += 10;
    });
}, 1000)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to externalyze your jquery in another file (without any  tags, just the jquery). And add a ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your JS code here
});
```

In the html, do as follow:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
<script src="<relative_path_to_your_js>">
```

The route /polls/ doesn't exist. So nothing happens. You only have routes `/` and `/get_more_tables` defined.

I did not understand the last question, what do you enter in the Interactive Console ? (After entering `./manage.py shell`)