# Getting jquery error $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a small HTML page in which `jquery` library is being called but I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('fetch.php/adds/3',function(data) {
            $('#div-adds').html(data);
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    </div>
    <div id="parent-container">
        <div class="middle-cont" id="result-div">
            <div class="left-panel"> 
                <div  id="div-restaurants"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-panel">
                <div id="div-adds"></div>        
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It's necessary to load jQuery before you try to use it...

Comment: You are using it before the jquery script is added

Comment: Put your scripts sources in the head _before_ your function

Comment: It's like a pair of shoes, you can't wear them before you bought them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3):

Ordering problem. Loading the library after executing the code? change order to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('fetch.php/adds/3',function(data) {
            $('#div-adds').html(data);
        });

    });
</script>
```