# PHP/Jquery - Echoing jquery in a PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function loader($time,$page){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.register-container').hide();
            $('.top-color').animate({height:'100%'}, 500);
                window.setTimeout(  
                    function() {  
                         $('.loading-overlay').show();
                    },  
                    600
                );
                //Simulate loading... and then redirect.
                window.setTimeout(  
                    function() {  
                         $('.loading-overlay').hide();
                         $('.top-color').animate({height:'0px'}, 500);
                    },  
                    2600
                );




        }); 

    </script>";
    echo '<div class="loading-overlay" >
                      <div class="loading-circles">
                        <!-- MAINTAINS CONSISTANT COLOR CENTER -->
                        <div class="circle hold" ></div>
                        <!-- ITERATION POINT FOR ANIMATION -->
                        <div class="circle first"></div>
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- ICON -->
                      <div class="name"><img src="images/loader/loadertext-green.png" /></div>
           </div>';
    echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=$time;URL='$page'>";
}
```

Which **should** add the above jQuery code to the page, and execute it.

Now my problem is, that when the function is called in the page, like below:

```
<?php
if($checksuccess){ loader("4","/account"); }
?>
```

I get the following jQuery error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you forgot to include `jQuery` file. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27476708/2962442

Comment: change instances of `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: @MichaelDoye it won't work, he doesn't link jQuery JavaScript file

Comment: @kmlnvm I have loaded jQuery file at the bottom of my page.

Comment: you cannot load it on the bottom when script is before

Comment: You need to place the `jQuery` CDN or whatever you are using before you run this code..

Comment: Or place this code after the `jQuery` src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php is expecting a variable name after the $ sign because you are using double quotes.

Try changes the single quotes with double quotes inside the echo and sorround it with single quotes. The opposite that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `echo` block starts and ends with a single quote, it should be a double quote.  Also, the string inside of an echo must escape double quotes.  You can generally use single quotes in html, but it is probably better to escape the double quotes.

`echo "<div class=\"loading-overlay\" >
                      <div class=\"loading-circles\">
Use escape \" on html attributes when echoing from PHP
           </div></div>";`