# JQuery autocomplete not showing dropdown options

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery autocomplete in my application using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = [{"value":"one"},{"value":"two"}];
    $("#company").autocomplete({
        source:data,
        select: function(e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault() // <--- Prevent the value from being inserted.
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

I have a text input with an id of `company`

I am using `jQuery-2.1.3.min.js` stored locally on my server

When I type into the text input, nothing is displaying. In the console, I can see an error on the line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

the error is saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

What could be causing this issue? I have also tried including jQuery version 1.10.2 and this made no difference

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Link jquery first, and then only then, link the others js codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include `jQuery` first :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

And then your other scripts (JS) :

```
<script src=".."> </script>
```

Comment: Can you try a put those 2 links (from `jQuery`) at the beginning of your code (that you just linked).

Comment: Those ones : `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>` and
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: ok i put them right up the top and still get the same reference error

Comment: Can you please check your console and tell me if all your JS files are being loaded correctly?

Comment: they are - its just that one reference error in the console now

Comment: Can you please make a JSFiddle with only the essential things (We've checked most of the things that could make that error happened).

Comment: My bad, you have to include the jQueryUI file ( it's from there that you get the function autocomplete) : `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js`. Also, please change your array formatting and go for a thing like that : `var data = ["one", "two", "three"];`

Comment: in what order should i include them ?

Comment: Both `jQuery` in no particular order, just before your other JS files (you could go `jQuery` -> `jQueryUI` -> other JS files

Comment: so i have included these: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`
 but its still not working

Comment: Please change the `//` to `https://`, those files aren't on your computer (the UI one at least). Pastebin : http://pastebin.com/Wd13vZmx

Comment: Check pastebin please and download firebug, you should have had a `404 Error` when adding the files I gave you (that I forgot to mention that you had to change the `//`).