# ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to do some stuff with jquery-ui calendar. When page is load it gives me these errors.

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$('document').ready(function () {

I tried so many answers googling. Still I got this error.

```
<%@page import="com.misyn.ems.service_impl.CasualLeaveServiceImpl"%>
<%@page import="com.misyn.ems.domain.emp.Person"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.misyn.ems.service.CasualLeaveService"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Casual Leave Application</title>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Resources/css/casual.css">

<body>
<jsp:include page="layout"></jsp:include>
    <div id="wrapper">   
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Leave Registration
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <a href="index.jsp">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Leave Registration..
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" style="border: black; ">
                    <div class="modal-content" >
                        <form>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h2 style="  font-style: oblique;color:#0066ff;text-align: center;">Pending Leave Details</h2>
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:75%" align ="center" >
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Date of Submission</th>      
                                                <th>From Days</th>
                                                <th>To Days</th>
                                                <th>Day Count</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>00-00-0000</td>
                                                <td>00-00-0000</td>
                                                <td>00-00-0000</td>
                                                <td>0</td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>   

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="width: 90%; float: inside;">

                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="jumbotron" style="padding: 25px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label>Select Leave Type</label>

                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button class="btn btn0 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu0" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select--
                                            <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-inverse0" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu0">
                                            <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="casual" class="list0" href="#">Casual Leave</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="annual" class="list0" href="#">Annual Leave</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="medical" class="list0" href="#">Medical Leave</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div> 
                            <br/>
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label>Employee Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" readonly id="employee_name"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label>Select Employee Name</label>

                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <i class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-inverse"></i>
                                        <button class="btn btn1 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" >--Select--
                                            <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-inverse1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                        <c:forEach items="${personList}" var="person">
                                            <li role="presentation"><a  data-myAttribute1="${person.getId()}" class="list1" href="#">${person.getName()}</a></li>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                    </ul>

                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label>Employee No.</label>  
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"   id="employee_no" readonly/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label>EPF No.</label>  
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"   id="epf_no" readonly/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="show_error">
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class=" jumbotron" style="padding: 25px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:75%" align ="center" id="mytable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Entitlement Day</th>      
                                    <th>No Of used Days</th>
                                    <th>Bal Avb. Days</th>
                                    <th>Pending Days</th>
                                    <th>Available Days</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="text-align: center;">
                                    <td id="entitled">$$</td>
                                    <td id="used">$$</td>
                                    <td id="bal">$$</td>
                                    <td class="pending" data-toggle="modal" id="pend">$$</td>
                                    <td class="avb_days" id="avb">$$</td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" jumbotron" style="padding: 25px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label>From</label>  
                                <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" readonly />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label>To.</label>  
                                <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" readonly/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label id="lblError" style="visibility:hidden; color: red; font-size: large">You'r applying leave amount is more than you available leave amount. 
                                    The extra amount will go as no pay leave. </label>  

                            </div>
                        </div> 


                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label>Select Leave Amount</label>  
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn2 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu2" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select--
                                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu2">
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list2" href="#">Half Day Morning</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list2" href="#">Half Day Evening</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list2" href="#">Whole Day</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list2" href="#">Short Day Morning</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list2" href="#">Short Day Evening</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label>Select Leave Amount</label>  
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn3 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu3" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select--
                                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu3">
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list3" href="#">Half Day Morning</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list3" href="#">Half Day Evening</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list3" href="#">Whole Day</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list2" href="#">Short Day Morning</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a class="list2" href="#">Short Day Evening</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <label>Select Coverup Person</label>  
                                  <div class="dropdown">
                                      <button class="btn btn4 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu4" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select--
                                          <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu3">
                                          <li role="presentation"><a class="list4" href="#">Name1</a></li>
                                          <li role="presentation"><a class="list4" href="#">Name2</a></li>

                                      </ul>
                                  </div>
                              </div> 
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label>Remarks</label>  
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Enter your remarks to supervisor.."></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">Save</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">Clear</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker1,#datepicker2").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        });

    });</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-inverse1 li > a').click(function () {
            var $myValue = $(this).attr("data-myAttribute1");
            $.get('CasualLeaveController2', {
                personid: $myValue, leave_type: "CASUAL"
            },
            function (data) {
                if (data !== null) {
                    var values = data.split("-");
                    $('#employee_no').val(values[0]);
                    $('#epf_no').val(values[1]);
                    $('#employee_name').val(values[2] + " " + values[3]);
                    $('#entitled').text(values[4]);
                    $('#used').text(values[5]);
                    $('#bal').text(values[6]);
                    $('#pend').text(values[7]);
                    $('#avb').text(values[8]);

                } else {
                    $('#show_error').text("Error Loading employee data");
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-inverse0 li > a').click(function () {
            var $myValue = $(this).attr("data-myAttribute0");
            if ($myValue === "casual") {
                $('.btn4').prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else if ($myValue === "medical") {
                $('.btn4').prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                $('.btn4').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
    });</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".list0").click(function () {
            $(".btn0:first-child").text($(this).text());
            $(".btn0:first-child").val($(this).text());
        });
    });</script>    
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".list1").click(function () {
            $(".btn1:first-child").text($(this).text());
            $(".btn1:first-child").val($(this).text());
        });
    });</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".list2").click(function () {
            $(".btn2:first-child").text($(this).text());
            $(".btn2:first-child").val($(this).text());
        });
    });</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".list3").click(function () {
            $(".btn3:first-child").text($(this).text());
            $(".btn3:first-child").val($(this).text());
        });
    });</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".list4").click(function () {
            $(".btn4:first-child").text($(this).text());
            $(".btn4:first-child").val($(this).text());
        });
    });</script>
<script>

    $('#mytable tr').each(function () {
        var avb = $(this).find(".avb_days").html();
    });</script>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('.pending').click(function () {
            $('#addModal').modal('show');
            // call load method
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
```

i tried lots of similar questions. Still can't find. Please help me. I know this is seems to be duplicated. But somehow it is not. It is because of the various ids I had added for dropdowns. (I guess). Please help. Thank you.

Comment: `$('document')` Don't need quotes here, use `$(document)`

Comment: @Tushar: True. Doesn't fit the symptom, though. (And I think it's such a common error they kinda slipped in support for it...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/gv6pxdbc/) - literally a copy and paste of the code in your question.

Comment: Maybe `language` attribute?

Comment: @Tushar: It's ignored.

Comment: But for me it still gives same error. Should I copy paste whole jsp page?

Comment: Are you running it locally?

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake: No. But you might want to copy and paste the HTML it produces. But really, just looking in the web console should tell you what's wrong. Clearly, for some reason, that script tag including jQuery isn't working -- either the JSP isn't outputting it, or it's not outputting it correctly, or that URL is blocked for you (works fine for me).

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake sorry just saw you are setting absolute URL, so forgive my previous comment. Aren't you setting somewhere `jQuery.noConflict();`? Same error if you use `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: I really don't understand why people putting downvote to my question. You don't even even know it is duplicated or it has some fatal error.. Nobody wants to know it.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me what should I do.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out after two days. My jsp page was load within the home page so home page also calling those from jquery inside the project. I removed my jsp's cdn and let home page to call those inside jquery. Thank you so much for your help all. 
Ps: I feel so stupid. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery instead $

so

```
jQuery('document').ready(function () {
jQuery("#datepicker1,#datepicker2").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});});
```

Comment: No dear. Still same. :(

Comment: im a bit confused looking at ur code

there are several "script" tags underneath the html structure and 2 document ready

have u tried combining them in order to avoid several script tags? so u would just have one single script tag where the whole js/jquery is