# Keep Getting an Error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add my input onto a list but I keep getting an error.
Can anyone please help me?
Here is the code:

HTML:

```
        <div class="add-item">
            <input id="item-add" type='text' placeholder="Enter item to shopping list..." name="itemAdd"></input>
            <button class="add-btn">Add Item</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item-list">
            <H2>Shopping List</H2>
            <ul class="shop-list">
                <li><input type="checkbox">Item 1</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox">Item 2</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox">Item 3</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox">Item 4</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox">Item 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-btn").click(function (){
        var x = $('#item-add').val();
        $(".shop-list").append('x');
    });

});
```

Comment: did you include jQuery in the page...

Comment: have you included jquery file

Comment: And if you think you've included it, check it for typos.

Comment: if included... did you use `noConflict` option... if so try `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`

Comment: yes i have:  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: @DavidTrinh: Unless you are being deliberately obfuscating, `app.js` is not jQuery.

Comment: sorry copied wrong item: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `https://` or `http://` part of the URL for a `src` in the `<script>` tag. Simply `code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js` will not find it:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure jQuery is included first, before your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the jQuery library. Add this in the head section.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`