# TypeScript with Jquery

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" please find my code below.

```
///<reference path="jquery.d.ts" />

class Test {
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = "gowtham";
    }

    dispname() {
        alert("Name :" + this.name);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    debugger;
    var test = new Test();
    $('#test').on('click', function() {
        debugger;
        test.dispname();
    });

});
```

i am having the referance too **reference path="jquery.d.ts"**  in my .ts file. Am i missing anything here .?

Comment: can you update your code to include the reference as well? are you sure that it's in the right path?

Comment: never mind, it's there, I edited the question with code formatting. still, are you sure the `d.ts` file is in the same path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a runtime error because you haven't loaded JQuery properly, if the issue was with the typings then you would've seen a compiler error.

See existing question:
[Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)