# "Stopping the execution because density of top bars is high"

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am in the process of building a local weather app on [codepen](http://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/OXoKYv). I am using `geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` method to get the current position, storing the respective longitude and latitude values in `lat` and `lng` variables. Although when i use console.log() statements, it seems like the longitude and lat values are not returned at all. on top of which i am getting the following messages in my console:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.

> Stopping the execution because density of top bars is high:  Object

Although i kindaa get the first error, I am a complete loss with the next two and a google search returned nothing of note.
 The following is my Javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var location = document.getElementsByClassName("location");

  getLocation();

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
    }
  }

  function getPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(lat);
    var weatherURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/c1d9333a91ec52f6/conditions/q/" + lat + "," + lng + ".json",
      forecastURL = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/c1d9333a91ec52f6/forecast/q/" + lat + "," + lng + ".json";

    $.getJSON(weatherURL, weatherJSON);

    function weatherJSON(jsonVal) {
      console.log(jsonVal);
      var currentLocation = jsonVal.currentObservation.display_location.full;
      location.innerHTML = currentLocation;

    }
  }
});
```

I would like the reader to kindly explain the errors and present a solution so that the final log statement displays to the console the complete JSON file thats being fetched by the getJSON method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: the fix that that error is the same as every error of that type, you have a reference called `navi` that does not exist. There is no magic interpretation of this.

Comment: how do i fix this on codepen? what about the other error?

Comment: did you read the entire Help Section before posting? I clearly states [one question per question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The biggest problem with your question is that it's a wall of code -- much of which isn't necessary to debug your problem. Can you reproduce your issue with only a few lines of code? Post that instead.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling my bad. edited the question. Also provided a new codepen link.

Comment: @snow Much better. Always post a [mcve]. Have a +1 for bettering your question. More importantly, you got something far better -- a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have succesfully debugged your code.

1) `getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins` This is because Chrome forbids to get location if the site that is requesting is using HTTP and not HTTPS. Solution: **load codepen via https://**

2) Because of the above issue, you have to load wunderground also with HTTPS. **https://api.wunderground.com/api/(...)**

X) `Stopping the execution because density of top bars is high: Object` **I didn't see that error in the console.**

X) `pen.js:95 Uncaught ReferenceError: navi is not defined` **Same as above.**

4) You had a typo, where `lon` should be **lng**

5) You had another typo(s), where you were accessing the JSON with this property `.currentObservation` which doesn't exist, should be **.current_observation**

6) Don't use `location` for a variable name, it references the browser's internal `window.location` object. Solution: change it to something like **locationDiv**

6.1) In the second line of your code you have `var locationDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("location")` with this you retrieve an array. If you want to actually assign an element you have to add an index: **document.getElementsByClassName("location")[0]**
Apply the same to the other elements you have at the top of your code.

With all the above, here you have a codepen which works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAvgRX

Note: Now I see that you updated with a shorter codepen. I was working in your first codepen.

Comment: two typos... i am ashamed of myself. whats strange is i am still getting the `Stopping the execution because density of top bars is high: Object` error although its not breaking anything. here: http://imgur.com/a/FxOGN

Comment: Guessing that the message is being generated by the real-time view created via codepen.