# how to implement j-query plug in?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't manage to successfully link jQuery to my html. I have made the most simple jQuery code possible just so I know it's right, and I've tried everything I can think of - searching hasn't been helpful..

my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="test.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="orange"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add your code here.?

Comment: Have you definitely linked a CDN/Local copy of jQuery to your `<head>` using the `<script>` tag?

Comment: You linked the script that uses jQuery _before_ jQuery itself. There’s your mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: yes..$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').fadeIn('slow');
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you need to add a jquery library

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

second: check your jquery working or not like

```js
<script>
   $(function(fn){
 alert('Wow its workig');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is already there. Don’t misuse the snippet editor. To check whether code is working, use the _browser console_, not `alert`s.