# Uncaught Reference:$ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to coding...just wanted to know what am i doing wrong in this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // This example loads the "Canadian Parliament 2012"
    // dataset from a CSV instead of from JSON.        // System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    $(function()  {
        Dimensions = "sector_type";
        Measures = "";
        tblname = "sample";
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:5000/api/values/5"
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            traditional: true,
            async: false,

        }).success(function results(data) {
            chartdata = data.data;
            alert("SUCCESS");
        });





    });

</script>
```

This is giving me Uncaught Reference :$ is not defined.Also is this the right way of writing a small script for retrieving data from localhost:5000 and what should i do to display the data
Any Help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: did you include jquery script?

Comment: Check Jquery plugin is referenced to your page

Comment: your var $ is not defined. you need to include query script for defining $ var.

Comment: `Also is this the right way of writing a small script for retrieving data from localhost:5000` - if it's a different host and/or port, does the server issue CORS headers? As for `async: false` - you'll get deprecation warnings about synchronous network requests - one day, it may just stop working altogether

Comment: can you confirm that you have included the JQuery library in your page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: @ochi yea..i've included JQuery library

Comment: @Jaromanda X what do you mean ??

Comment: @Venky - you seem to have discovered the synchronous request warning 3 hours ago ... as far as CORS goes, wait and see

Comment: @JaromandaX Yea synchronous thing is now ok now, thanks a lot for your help though,but for some reason it says connection refused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worked for me.
You should put the reference jQuery link.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then replace the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
Dimensions = "sector_type";
Measures = "";
tblname = "sample";
data = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
method: "GET",
url: "http://localhost:5000/api/values/5",
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
traditional: true,
async: false,
success:function(data){
chartdata = data.data;
alert("SUCCESS");
} 
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/...am i missing something ??

Comment: Hi @venky async: true,

Comment: thanks a lot,it seems to be working,but for some reason it says connection refused,im running this on linux

Answer (score 0):

Try my code.. I think it will work fine

```
(function () {
    Dimensions = "sector_type";
    Measures = "";
    tblname = "sample";
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/values/5",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        traditional: true,
        async: false
    }).success(function results(data) {
        chartdata = data.data;
        alert("SUCCESS");
    });
})();
```

Comment: if the JQuery library is not referenced in the page, the error will be the same with this piece of code :/ - moving pieces around does not seem to be the issue here

Comment: He is not mentioned which file he inserted or not and you are right dude!! J query file must be added

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).ready(function(){});`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// This example loads the "Canadian Parliament 2012"
// dataset from a CSV instead of from JSON.        // System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
$(document).ready(function()  { 
    Dimensions = "sector_type";
    Measures = "";
    tblname = "sample";
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/values/5"
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        traditional: true,
        async: false,

    }).success(function results(data) {
        chartdata = data.data;
        alert("SUCCESS");
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: if the JQuery library is not referenced in the page, the error will be the same with this piece of code :/

Answer (score 0):

check whether you've included the jquery library in your html code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is not really an answer, more of a comment

Answer (score 0):

$ is not defined means you have not added jQuery plugin in your page.

Download jQuery plugin from jquery.com and add in your project. Reference that file in your page header.

For displaying data, it depend on what data you are retrieving. According to return data add control and bind.

```
$(function()  {

    Dimensions = "sector_type";
    Measures = "";
    tblname = "sample";

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/values/5"
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        success:function (data) {
        chartdata = data.data;
        alert("SUCCESS");
         }
    });
});
```