# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript. at bootstrap.min.js:6

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I tried to include the bootstrap and jquery file into my project but when i do it. it gives me error. "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.     at bootstrap.min.js:6" this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">
<!-- Scripts -->
<style>
.topd{
    background-color: #3498DB;
    padding: 14px 16px;
   font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
   color : white;
   /* color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); */
}
.zbody{
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topd">
<h1>Welcome to HopesV2.0</h1>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light w3-teal" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        HR
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<BR>
<!-- Start Body -->
<div class="jumbotron zbody">
  <h1>Basic Information</h1>
  <hr class="my-4">
<p class="lead">

    <a class="btn btn-primary " href="#" role="button">Submit</a>
  </p>
</div>
<!-- End Body -->  
</body>
</html>
```

i already download the files into my project but it keeps me getting errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: First of all: script in head?
Second: put jquery first yeah, after that the bootstrapand your own as last one

Have you taken a look at this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start   ?

Comment: @sta try to inspect the page and make sure jquery loaded properly

Comment: is it wrong to put the script in head ?

Comment: this error also appeared Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://localhost/zeephp/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'qUkhuOyYIAtXci49DBDOy7Y4hsKDni/2O4xbdSW9k9E='. The resource has been blocked.

Comment: @starosacompany, not wrong, it's just a better pratice to put it at the bottom of your page, so that the js renders after the page is shown instead of before

Answer (score 1):

add your external files as follows

you can add js files in `header` or in `footer` but maintain this order

Load Jquery first and then add bootstrap js

[Reference](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">



<body>
<div class="topd">
<h1>Welcome to HopesV2.0</h1>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light w3-teal" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        HR
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<BR>
<!-- Start Body -->
<div class="jumbotron zbody">
  <h1>Basic Information</h1>
  <hr class="my-4">
<p class="lead">

    <a class="btn btn-primary " href="#" role="button">Submit</a>
  </p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: i solve it by removing the  "integrity code part" . may i know whats the use of that part ?

Comment: refer this for integrity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script its mainly for `CDNs` not needed for local files.

Comment: before loading bootstrap.min.js you need to load jquery and then follow the bootstrap's order