# Unable to load jQuery via Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. In this this app, I'm building a SPA with Vue and webpack. At this time, I'm trying to import this [datepicker](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) control.

Unfortunately, webpack seems to be causing issues. The main dependency, jQuery, won't seem to load and I don't understand why.

I have the following:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My App</title>

    <script src="~/js/shared.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict";

const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        shared: './src/js/shared.js',
        page: './src/js/page.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            moment: 'moment',
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'shared' })
    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: "/js/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue']
    }
};
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<h2>Welcome</h2>
<hr />

<div id="view" v-cloak>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"><h5>Selection Details</h5></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-8">
                  <label for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
                  <date-picker v-model="birthDate"></date-picker>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/page.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

**page.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import datePicker from 'vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker';

$(document).ready(function () {
    var v = new Vue({
        el: document.getElementById('view'),
        components: {
            "datePicker": datePicker
        },
        data: {
          birthDate: null
        }
    }
});
```

When this page loads in the browser, I see the following error in the console window:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*

I suspect that this is the reason the datepicker isn't working in my page properly. I don't understand this error. From my understanding, the line `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ ...` should've handle this issue. When I look at the "shared.bundle.js" file that gets generated, I can see the jQuery content at the top. This confuses me even more. I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, ProviderPlugin should have made jquery available globally.

Try adding in `page.js` this line `import $ from 'jquery';` to your imports.

Comment: I tried that and received the same error. The really confusing part is that I can see jQuery in the shared.bundle.js file.