# Encoded JavaScript: How to decode?

Tags: javascript, encryption, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I recently bought a script from a guy that isn't replying anymore, and left me with the script obfuscated and not working. The thing is that everything works except the encoded part, which gives error.
I've tried every website on google to un-obfuscate this, with no luck.

How can I "decrypt" this part to make this script work?

```
var _0x4091 =
['.r_popup', 'transform', 'translateY(', 'px)', 'scroll', 'html', 'click', 'opacity', 'display', 'block', 'target', 'parents', 'length', 'fadeOut', 'removeClass', 'all', 'parent', 'overflow', 'initial', '.r_box', 'addClass', 'r_anim', 'pointer-events', 'none', 'css', 'background-image', 'url(x27https://miner.eu/svg/circle.svgx27)', '.r_popup_container', 'fadeIn', 'fast', 'r_pointer', 'fixed', 'top', 'body', 'scrollTop']; (function (a, c) { var b = function (b) { while (--b) { a['push'](a['shift']()); } }; b(++c); }(_0x4091, 0x12b)); var _0x1409 = function (a, c) { a = a - 0x0; var b = _0x4091[a]; return b; }; var shown = 0x0; function verify() { if (shown == 0x0) { $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x1')](_0x1409('0x2'))['css'](_0x1409('0x3'), _0x1409('0x4')); setTimeout(function () { $('.r_box')[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x6'), _0x1409('0x7')); }, 0xfa); setTimeout(function () { $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x9')](_0x1409('0xa')); $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x1')]('r_pointer'); $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x6'), _0x1409('0x4')); shown = 0x1; updatePos(); }, 0x730); } else { $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x9')](_0x1409('0xa')); $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x1')](_0x1409('0xb'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x3'), _0x1409('0x4')); } } function updatePos() { if (shown == 0x1 && $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x5')]('position') != _0x1409('0xc')) { var a = $(_0x1409('0x8'))['offset']()[_0x1409('0xd')] - $(_0x1409('0xe'))[_0x1409('0xf')](); dist = a * -0x1; if (a < 0x0) { if (a > 0x14) { $(_0x1409('0x10'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x11'), _0x1409('0x12') + dist + _0x1409('0x13')); } } else if (a >= 0x0) { if (a < 0xdc) { $(_0x1409('0x10'))[_0x1409('0x5')]('transform', _0x1409('0x12') + dist + _0x1409('0x13')); } else { $(_0x1409('0x10'))[_0x1409('0x5')]('transform', _0x1409('0x12') + -0xdc + _0x1409('0x13')); } } } else { $(_0x1409('0x10'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x11'), _0x1409('0x12') + 0x0 + 'px)'); } } $(window)[_0x1409('0x14')](function () { if (shown == 0x1) { updatePos(); } }); $(_0x1409('0x15'))[_0x1409('0x16')](function (a) { if ($('.r_popup_container')[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x17')) == '1' && $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x18')) == _0x1409('0x19')) { if (a[_0x1409('0x1a')]['id'] != _0x1409('0x8') && $(a[_0x1409('0x1a')])[_0x1409('0x1b')](_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x1c')] == 0x0) { $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x1d')](_0x1409('0xa')); $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x1e')](_0x1409('0xb'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x3'), _0x1409('0x1f')); } } }); $('.r_all')['parent']()[_0x1409('0x20')]()[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x21'), _0x1409('0x22'));
```

the error is:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined [Learn More] test.js:25:1942 The
>   character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document
>   will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the
>   document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The
>   character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in
>   the transfer protocol. a.html ReferenceError: $ is not defined [Learn
>   More] test.js:25:685

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Sorry, the error is: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Learn More]
test.js:25:1942
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
a.html
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Learn More]
test.js:25:685`

Comment: sounds like jQuery is undefined. it would be quite reasonable, since there are tons of references which makes me think that it depends on jQuery. Including it would be quite enough.

Comment: First of all, run it through something like http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: @briosheje is right, add JQuery to your project and this script will run without errors. https://jsfiddle.net/bfn07wLa/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: I've updated my answer, @unkn0wnx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, run it all through a [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/), to get some proper indentation.

```js
var _0x4091 = ['.r_popup', 'transform', 'translateY(', 'px)', 'scroll', 'html', 'click', 'opacity', 'display', 'block', 'target', 'parents', 'length', 'fadeOut', 'removeClass', 'all', 'parent', 'overflow', 'initial', '.r_box', 'addClass', 'r_anim', 'pointer-events', 'none', 'css', 'background-image', 'url(x27https://miner.eu/svg/circle.svgx27)', '.r_popup_container', 'fadeIn', 'fast', 'r_pointer', 'fixed', 'top', 'body', 'scrollTop'];
    (function(a, c) {
        var b = function(b) {
            while (--b) {
                a['push'](a['shift']());
            }
        };
        b(++c);
    }(_0x4091, 0x12b));
    
    var _0x1409 = function(a, c) {
        a = a - 0x0;
        var b = _0x4091[a];
        return b;
    };
    var shown = 0x0;
    
    function verify() {
        if (shown == 0x0) {
            $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x1')](_0x1409('0x2'))['css'](_0x1409('0x3'), _0x1409('0x4'));
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.r_box')[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x6'), _0x1409('0x7'));
            }, 0xfa);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x9')](_0x1409('0xa'));
                $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x1')]('r_pointer');
                $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x6'), _0x1409('0x4'));
                shown = 0x1;
                updatePos();
            }, 0x730);
        } else {
            $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x9')](_0x1409('0xa'));
            $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x1')](_0x1409('0xb'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x3'), _0x1409('0x4'));
        }
    }
    
    function updatePos() {
        if (shown == 0x1 && $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x5')]('position') != _0x1409('0xc')) {
            var a = $(_0x1409('0x8'))['offset']()[_0x1409('0xd')] - $(_0x1409('0xe'))[_0x1409('0xf')]();
            dist = a * -0x1;
            if (a < 0x0) {
                if (a > 0x14) {
                    $(_0x1409('0x10'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x11'), _0x1409('0x12') + dist + _0x1409('0x13'));
                }
            } else if (a >= 0x0) {
                if (a < 0xdc) {
                    $(_0x1409('0x10'))[_0x1409('0x5')]('transform', _0x1409('0x12') + dist + _0x1409('0x13'));
                } else {
                    $(_0x1409('0x10'))[_0x1409('0x5')]('transform', _0x1409('0x12') + -0xdc + _0x1409('0x13'));
                }
            }
        } else {
            $(_0x1409('0x10'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x11'), _0x1409('0x12') + 0x0 + 'px)');
        }
    }
    $(window)[_0x1409('0x14')](function() {
        if (shown == 0x1) {
            updatePos();
        }
    });
    $(_0x1409('0x15'))[_0x1409('0x16')](function(a) {
        if ($('.r_popup_container')[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x17')) == '1' && $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x18')) == _0x1409('0x19')) {
            if (a[_0x1409('0x1a')]['id'] != _0x1409('0x8') && $(a[_0x1409('0x1a')])[_0x1409('0x1b')](_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x1c')] == 0x0) {
                $(_0x1409('0x8'))[_0x1409('0x1d')](_0x1409('0xa'));
                $(_0x1409('0x0'))[_0x1409('0x1e')](_0x1409('0xb'))[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x3'), _0x1409('0x1f'));
            }
        }
    });
    $('.r_all')['parent']()[_0x1409('0x20')]()[_0x1409('0x5')](_0x1409('0x21'), _0x1409('0x22'));
```

`_0x1409` seems to be a wrapper function to get a key from the `_0x4091` array. We can replace all those with direct array access. Then we can remove the `_0x1409` method.

All the `0x..` values can be replaced with their decimal equivalent [using a deobfuscator](http://jsnice.org/):

```js
var map = [".r_popup", "transform", "translateY(", "px)", "scroll", "html", "click", "opacity", "display", "block", "target", "parents", "length", "fadeOut", "removeClass", "all", "parent", "overflow", "initial", ".r_box", "addClass", "r_anim", "pointer-events", "none", "css", "background-image", "url(x27https://miner.eu/svg/circle.svgx27)", ".r_popup_container", "fadeIn", "fast", "r_pointer", "fixed", "top", "body", "scrollTop"];

(function(depMap, opt_attributes) {
  var setter = function(val) {
    for (;--val;) {
      depMap["push"](depMap["shift"]());
    }
  };
  setter(++opt_attributes);
})(map, 299);

var shown = 0;

function verify() {
  if (shown == 0) {
    $(map[0])[map[1]](map[2])["css"](map[3], map[4]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".r_box")[map[5]](map[6], map[7]);
    }, 250);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(map[8])[map[9]](map[10]);
      $(map[0])[map[1]]("r_pointer");
      $(map[0])[map[5]](map[6], map[4]);
      shown = 1;
      updatePos();
    }, 1840);
  } else {
    $(map[8])[map[9]](map[10]);
    $(map[0])[map[1]](map[11])[map[5]](map[3], map[4]);
  }
}

function updatePos() {
  if (shown == 1 && $(map[8])[map[5]]("position") != map[12]) {
    var a = $(map[8])["offset"]()[map[13]] - $(map[14])[map[15]]();
    dist = a * -1;
    if (a < 0) {
      if (a > 20) {
        $(map[16])[map[5]](map[17], map[18] + dist + map[19]);
      }
    } else {
      if (a >= 0) {
        if (a < 220) {
          $(map[16])[map[5]]("transform", map[18] + dist + map[19]);
        } else {
          $(map[16])[map[5]]("transform", map[18] + -220 + map[19]);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    $(map[16])[map[5]](map[17], map[18] + 0 + "px)");
  }
}

$(window)[map[20]](function() {
  if (shown == 1) {
    updatePos();
  }
});

$(map[21])[map[22]](function(options) {
  if ($(".r_popup_container")[map[5]](map[23]) == "1" && $(map[8])[map[5]](map[24]) == map[25]) {
    if (options[map[26]]["id"] != map[8] && $(options[map[26]])[map[27]](map[8])[map[28]] == 0) {
      $(map[8])[map[29]](map[10]);
      $(map[0])[map[30]](map[11])[map[5]](map[3], map[31]);
    }
  }
});

$(".r_all")["parent"]()[map[32]]()[map[5]](map[33], map[34]);
```

Then there's a little snippet directly following the `map` that shifts around the methods a little, resulting in a new map:

```js
var map = [
    ".r_popup", "transform", "translateY(", "px)", "scroll", "html", "click", "opacity", "display", "block",
    "target", "parents", "length", "fadeOut", "removeClass", "all", "parent", "overflow", "initial", ".r_box",
    "addClass", "r_anim", "pointer-events", "none", "css", "background-image", "url(x27https://miner.eu/svg/circle.svgx27)", ".r_popup_container", "fadeIn", "fast",
    "r_pointer", "fixed", "top", "body", "scrollTop"];
    
(function(depMap, opt_attributes) {
  var setter = function(val) {
    for (;--val;) {
      depMap["push"](depMap["shift"]());
    }
  };
  setter(++opt_attributes);
})(map, 299);

console.log(map);
```

Now all that remains is replacing all occurrences of `map[num]` with their string equivalent, and replacing `["key"]` with `.key` where possible, for this end result:

```
var shown = 0;

function verify() {
  if (shown == 0) {
    $(".r_box").addClass("r_anim").css("pointer-events", "none");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".r_box").css("background-image", "url('https://miner.eu/svg/circle.svg')");
    }, 250);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".r_popup_container").fadeIn("fast");
      $(".r_box").addClass("r_pointer");
      $(".r_box").css("background-image", "none");
      shown = 1;
      updatePos();
    }, 1840);
  } else {
    $(".r_popup_container").fadeIn("fast");
    $(".r_box").addClass("r_pointer").css("pointer-events", "none");
  }
}

function updatePos() {
  if (shown == 1 && $(".r_popup_container").css("position") != "fixed") {
    var a = $(".r_popup_container").offset().top - $("body").scrollTop();
    dist = a * -1;
    if (a < 0) {
      if (a > 20) {
        $(".r_popup").css("transform", "translateY(" + dist + "px)");
      }
    } else {
      if (a >= 0) {
        if (a < 220) {
          $(".r_popup").css("transform", "translateY(" + dist + "px)");
        } else {
          $(".r_popup").css("transform", "translateY(" + -220 + "px)");
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    $(".r_popup").css("transform", "translateY(" + 0 + "px)");
  }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (shown == 1) {
    updatePos();
  }
});

$("html").click(function(options) {
  if ($(".r_popup_container").css("opacity") == "addClass" && $(".r_popup_container").css("display") == "block") {
    if (options.target.id != ".r_popup_container" && $(options.target).parents(".r_popup_container").length == 0) {
      $(".r_popup_container").fadeOut("fast");
      $(".r_box").removeClass("r_pointer").css("pointer-events", "all");
    }
  }
});

$(".r_all").parent().parent().css("overflow", "initial");
```

Comment: Wow man! Awesome! Thanks a lot! You are a very patient man! I have selected this as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var map = [
    ".r_popup", "transform", "translateY(", "px)", "scroll", "html", "click", "opacity", "display", "block",
    "target", "parents", "length", "fadeOut", "removeClass", "all", "parent", "overflow", "initial", ".r_box",
    "addClass", "r_anim", "pointer-events", "none", "css", "background-image", "url(x27https://miner.eu/svg/circle.svgx27)", ".r_popup_container", "fadeIn", "fast",
    "r_pointer", "fixed", "top", "body", "scrollTop"];
    
(function(depMap, opt_attributes) {
  var setter = function(val) {
    for (;--val;) {
      depMap["push"](depMap["shift"]());
    }
  };
  setter(++opt_attributes);
})(map, 299);

console.log(map);
```