# Error: ‘$’ is not defined.[no-undef]

Tags: jquery

I wanna use some jQuery to make a **sticky nav bar** but I get the errors

> `ERROR: ‘$’ is not defined. [no-undef].`
>   `ERROR: ‘document ’ is not defined. [no-undef]`

and the code doesn’t work. Can anybody help me why I get these errors and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you included Jquery library in your webpage?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't properly included a working jQuery URL on your web page

Comment: Thanks for answering,  I've already included Jquery library but still the same

Comment: by using this link:     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   the problem solved and it is working but the errors are not disapearing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include jquery library in the web and before your script.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did but still the errors are there

Answer (score 1):

I think your Jquery library is not loaded in Page otherwise your script loaded before Jquery.

So, Insert Jquery Library and your custom script like below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st one**: Your jquery file is not being properly loaded into your page

**2nd**: You have a botched version of jQuery. This could happen because someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable.

Comment: these are my scripts:

<script src="resourses/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

       <script src="vendors/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

      <script src="resourses/js/script.js"></script>