# $ is not defined - Ajax call in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to execute a JavaScript function. I get an error everytime the function enters the Ajax block saying:

> $ is not defined

How can I solve this problem? I'm Programming a `Google Chrome Addon` and I get this error in my .js file:

[image]

At the moment ther is just the function above and its caller in the file:

```
// Calls get_pw function
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', get_pw)
})
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Include `jQuery`!

Comment: `$` is a jQuery object. Perhaps if you want to continue this, include `jQuery` or proceed with the JS `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Include jQuery or make ajax call without jQuery as is told in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: OK thanks for the feedback I WOULD do this but I'm new to this topic and a big help would be if you could show me how for me its clear that i have to add something but not how -  and i couldn't find an answer which worked

Comment: why the downvote? -  cant I ask one question on this page without getting hated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui Abdaoui No, I'm working on my own project and encountered this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download jQuery from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js. Include it in head tag of your document and call get_pw() when document has loaded.

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Include jQuery before executing the function or [rewrite](https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/) AJAX request without jQuery.

Including can be done simply by copying jQuery code at the beginning of your script or by loading a file from [their CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) and then executing your script on a [callback](https://gist.github.com/jnrbsn/4268258)(slower).

Comment: What do you mean by _loading a file from their CDN via AJAX request_ ?