# javascript form get value with 2 functions javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log('Click détecté ');
        var form = document.createElement('form');
            form.setAttribute('method', 'GET');
            form.setAttribute('id', 'formSelectNbColumns');

            document.body.appendChild(form);


            let monSelect = document.createElement('select');
            monSelect.setAttribute('id', 'choice');
            monSelect.setAttribute('name', 'premier');
                let monOption = document.createElement('option');
                    monOption.setAttribute('value', 1);
                    monOption.innerText = 'choice1';
                    monSelect.appendChild(monOption);
                let monOption2 = document.createElement('option');
                    monOption2.setAttribute('value', 2);
                    monOption2.innerText = 'choice2';
                    monSelect.appendChild(monOption2);
           form.appendChild(monSelect);
            let input = document.createElement('input')
            input.setAttribute('type', "submit");

            input.setAttribute('value', "submit");
            form.appendChild(input);

            document.querySelector("#choice").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log('Click détecté pour la deuxieme fois'); 

let formSelect = $('#formSelectNbColumns');
            let optionSelected = $("option:selected", formSelect);
            console.log('Valeur sélectionné : ' + optionSelected.val());

       });
        }
    );


<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quelques langages</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="test">Ajouter un block</button>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

I'm trying to make a form with a javascript but I have a problem. I don't know how to get the value only with javascript. I wrote this code but it's not working. I don't understand why. I know this code is very simple but I want to understand how to do it.

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log('Click détecté ');

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'GET');
        form.setAttribute('id', 'formSelectNbColumns');

        document.body.appendChild(form);

        let monSelect = document.createElement('select');
        monSelect.setAttribute('name', 'premier');

        let monOption = document.createElement('option');
        monOption.setAttribute('value', 1);
        monOption.innerText = 'choice1';
        monSelect.appendChild(monOption);

        let monOption2 = document.createElement('option');
        monOption2.setAttribute('value', 2);
        monOption2.innerText = 'choice2';
        monSelect.appendChild(monOption2);
        form.appendChild(monSelect);

        let input = document.createElement('input')
        input.setAttribute('type', "submit");

        input.setAttribute('value', "submit");
        form.appendChild(input);

        document.querySelector("#choice").addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log('Click détecté pour la deuxieme fois');

            let formSelect = $('#formSelectNbColumns');
            let optionSelected = $("option:selected", formSelect);
            console.log('Valeur sélectionné : ' + optionSelected.val());
        });
    }
);


<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quelques langages</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="test">Ajouter un block</button>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You’re loading jQuery _after_ your `test.js` script. Change the order, see if that works. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Xufox I don’t think this is necessarily a duplicate. There isn’t even enough information to know.

Comment: it 's still not working the problem of my code it's when i submit my form i can't get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your script throws an error :

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

It is thrown by this line :

```
document.querySelector("#choice").addEventListener("click", function() {...});
```

It can be solved by making 'choice' the `id` of your `select` element :

```
monSelect.setAttribute('id', 'choice');
```

And as others have said in comments, you need to include the jQuery script before your test.js script :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Updated snippet :

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('Click détecté ');
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'GET');
        form.setAttribute('id', 'formSelectNbColumns');

        document.body.appendChild(form);

        let monSelect = document.createElement('select');
        monSelect.setAttribute('name', 'premier');
        monSelect.setAttribute('id', 'choice');
        let monOption = document.createElement('option');
        monOption.setAttribute('value', 1);
        monOption.innerText = 'choice1';
        monSelect.appendChild(monOption);
        let monOption2 = document.createElement('option');
        monOption2.setAttribute('value', 2);
        monOption2.innerText = 'choice2';
        monSelect.appendChild(monOption2);
        form.appendChild(monSelect);
        let input = document.createElement('input')
        input.setAttribute('type', "submit");
        input.setAttribute('value', "submit");
        form.appendChild(input);

        document.querySelector("#choice").addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log('Click détecté pour la deuxieme fois');

            let formSelect = $('#formSelectNbColumns');
            let optionSelected = $("option:selected", formSelect);
            console.log('Valeur sélectionné : ' + optionSelected.val());

        });
    }
);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quelques langages</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="test">Ajouter un block</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i add the id=choice  to my input but i have this error : TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: Sur quel input l'as tu ajouté? Dans la réponse je te conseille de l'ajouter sur la select.

Comment: j ai essayé sur le select mais des que je valide mon formulaire rien ne s affiche je suis supposé avoir le message : Click détecté pour la deuxième fois

Comment: Tu es sûr? Je l'ai testé dans mon snippet et ça marche. Peux-tu éditer ta question et ajouter la modification que tu as faite ?

Comment: @hlklbklk Ton premier snippet fonctionne. Celui où tu as ajouté l'id.

Comment: oui j arrive a avoir le message: click detecté mais pas le deuxieme message : Click détecté pour la deuxieme fois

Comment: @hlklbklk Cette deuxième erreur est du au fait que tu importes ton script test.js avant d'impoter jquery-3.3.1.min.js. Au moment où ton event handler est executé, jQuery n'est pas défini. Inverse le sens dans lequel tu importes les deux scripts.

Comment: merci ça marche

Comment: je ne sais pas comment faire peux tu m indiquer comment faire

Comment: Il devrait y avoir une sorte de case à cocher à côté de ma réponse, à gauche. Tu peux aussi lire ici, c'est expliqué : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979