# Code working on codepen but not in my text editor

Tags: javascript

The gradient degree on mouse movement isn't working in my text editor however it does in codepen.

https://codepen.io/glittergirl/pen/bjXOYd

I checked the console and it is coming up with: script.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
So I used

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $ */
```

However it is still coming up with the same error. Why is this?

HTML

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs
/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.2/
fullpage.css"/>

<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.2/
fullpage.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    css3: false
       });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div class="gradient">
</div>
```

Mousemove JS

```
$(".gradient").mousemove(function (event) {
'use strict';
var w = $(this).width(),
    pct = 360 * (+event.pageX) / w,
    bg = "linear-gradient(" + pct + "deg,#4ac1ff,#795bb0)";
$(".gradient").css("background-image", bg);
});
```

EDIT: after reordering jquery in html the console log no longer produces the error however code is still not working in my code editor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you include jQuery? Please post a [complete, working](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) HTML/JS file(s) that can replicate the issue so you can get an accurate answer.

Comment: Hi yes I have included jQuery, I updated my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: `<script src="script.js"></script>` is above your jQuery script.

Comment: The console log no longer has the error however it is still not working

Comment: @Trent not the same issue