# javascript stopped working but works on diffrent server

Tags: javascript

I need your help with a strange problem.

The company I work for has a company website. 
I have been updating pages on their website the last couple of days.

After updating, I decided to upload the website, 
but suddenly the javascript doesn't work anymore.

I get the following error when I press f12

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

base.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at base.js:1

On the [test server](http://socialmediabot.nl/html/asterisk.html) (my own server) it works without any problems.

On the [main server](https://www.aska-ltd.jp/asterisk.html) (company server) it doesn't work.

What could be the issue for this?
It's not on just one page, it's on every single page that the Javascript doesn't work.

[update]

I know about the different versions of Javascript. 
This is already fixed in the testing environment of the company website. 
This still doesn't fix the current problem.

Thank you

Wesley

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using jQuery for your JavaScript code.

The header of the first page contains a tag for loading jQuery:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But on the second page, you never load jQuery.

As I don't know how the file structure of your server is, I cannot tell you the exact path, but you need to make sure you load jQuery in a similar way on your company website.

EDIT:

I noticed that you load jQuery from `https://www.aska-ltd.jp/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js`. However, this file is not the original file (compared to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js` using MD5). If you want to use this old version (**not** recommended), you can try to re-download it or simply load jQuery in its latest version from its official server (recommended).

Comment: I fixed this in the testing environment of the company website. Doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On the test site you use jQuery 3.3.1:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On the main site you use jQuery 1.10.1:

```
<script src="https://www.aska-ltd.jp/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Please both use v3 if you don't have specific needs.

Comment: I fixed this in the testing environment of the company website. Doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
swiper.min.js:16 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
base.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at base.js:1
fadein.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at fadein.js:24

Comment: In my test, I copy all code from your main site, and simply change "https://www.aska-ltd.jp/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" to "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" will work. I still think it's is the jQuery version problem.

Comment: @WesleySchravendijk As you can see from the first line, there is a problem with your jQuery file. It is not original.

Answer (score 0):

As @NoobTW and @SapuSeven have said, there is an error in the jQuery script on the production site.

On the production site, try replacing this `<script src="https://www.aska-ltd.jp/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`
 with this `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Also, if you load jQuery from a CDN, it may help simplify things. Here is one option for jQuery 3: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

See here for more options: https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery never loads at all on the main server. I tried taking the code from the file on the server and evaluating it, but discovered some sort of corruption in the JQuery file your server is returning:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools showing source of jquery-1.10.1.min.js with strange characters in it and failing to evaluate it in the console because of a SyntaxError.]

If the same thing happens with an updated version of JQuery, check whether it’s also corrupted. It may be some sort of transformation the server is incorrectly performing.