# jQuery datatables not displaying data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Using AJAX to pull data and display in datatables however its not displaying in the table ..
ok my jquery datatables code is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
        url:"data/companylist-ajax.php",
        success:function(data)  {
          var myobj = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#companylist').DataTable(
        "data": myobj,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "regoffice_city" },
            { "data": "regoffice_country" },
            { "data": "is_customer" },
            { "data": "is_supplier" }
        ]
      )
    }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

My PHP code for the JSON data is

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `comp_companies` LIMIT 0, 500");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

do { $newdata = json_encode($result); echo $newdata; } while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
```

The data displayed on the page is

```
{"company_id":"1","company_sector":"0","company_type":"TEST-COMP","individual":"0","name":"Test Ltd","regoffice_1":"18 Alma Road","regoffice_2":"","regoffice_3":"","regoffice_city":"Hinckley","regoffice_county":"Leicestershire","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","regoffice_postcode":"LE10 1PN","is_customer":"1","customer_approved":"0","is_supplier":"0","supplier_approved":"0","registration_no":"123"}
```

Its displaying the data when I access the page directly however it wont display in the datatables

Don't know if im doing something wrong or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax option of the datatable like this

```
 $('#companylist').DataTable({
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: {
      url: "data/companylist-ajax.php",
      type: 'POST'
    },

    aLengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50], [10, 25, 50]], 
    bPaginate:true,
    scrollX: "100%",
    order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    scrollCollapse: true,
    columns: [
      { "data": "name" },
      { "data": "regoffice_city" },
      { "data": "regoffice_country" },
      { "data": "is_customer" },
      { "data": "is_supplier" }
    ]
  });
```

And the json response from the server should be like this

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Abc",
      "xyz",
      "abc",
      "yes",
      "no"
    ],
    [
      "Pqr",
      "xyz",
      "abc",
      "no",
      "yes"
    ],
}
```

Comment: Im now getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(document).ready(function() { <-- This Line
  $('#companylist').DataTable({

Comment: @ChrisYates do you have jquery included in your project?

Comment: <!-- jQuery 3 -->
 <script src="assets/vendor_components/jquery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

 <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
 <script src="assets/vendor_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

I have also tried a CDN instead of my local version but still same

Comment: make sure you are loading jquery before you do this `$(document).ready(function() {` ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined ... alternatively, use `jquery(document).ready(function($)` to pass jquery as `$` ... you are going to want to do this if you think there is a conflict between jquery scripts (i.e. if there are more than 1 included in the project wihout you knowing)

Comment: Ah lol whoops !
Thanks for pointing out the obvious .. cant believe I was that stupid

Comment: @ChrisYates no problem, dude. is your code working now?

Comment: its saying invalid json response now

Comment: Check the answer now i have added the json response should be like that