# Intermittent ReferenceError: $ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

Adding a background color to the nav on scroll, and it will randomly not work. I would say 50% of the time it works, 50% I get the ReferenceError. This is multiple devices, and multiple browsers, multiple pages.

```js
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $(document).scroll(function () {
                var $nav = $(".masthead");
                $nav.toggleClass('navBG', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
              });
            });
</script>
```

```css
.masthead{width:100%;height:80px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:9999;box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;}
.masthead.navBG{box-shadow:0 5px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);background-color:#01417E; !important;transition:background-color 100ms linear;}
```

```html
<div class="masthead">
      
      <nav id="sidenavContainer" class="sidenav">
                <!-- SOME LIs -->
                <!-- JS for Nav Functionality -->
      </nav>
        
      <div id="navTri" onclick="openNav()"><img src="menu.svg" alt="Menu" width="30"></div>
      
      <div id="logoMain"><a href="#"><img src="logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a></div>
      
</div>
```

Error seems to show up consistently in the code snippet. Any thoughts?

Comment: there is not `jquery` included in your snippet

Comment: In the snippet at least, jQuery isn't imported anywhere. As for why it's happening to you, maybe check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined?rq=1).

Comment: Can you add the code where you include jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Sounds like 50% of the time your jQuery file does not load. Also why are you listening to scroll on the document?

Comment: Is your custom script below jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use async, remove it.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

Maybe try defer attribute if you want.

**scripts marked *async* are executed in casual order, when they become available. Scripts marked defer are executed (after parsing completes) in the order which they are defined in the markup.**

But then, **defer** your script as well, as order matters, and you don't want your script to execute before jquery loads, which is what happens sometimes with async in your case.

Comment: Makes sense and that seems to have fixed it. Unfortunately I can't remember why I had that there. Hoping I didn't need it for something else. Thanks!