# How to get a value from a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

This is my function I'm trying to get button's value and display HTML for every element correctly but when I do a click on my button I have this error.

```
function prueba() {
    var value = $("button").val();
    alert(value);
}
```

This is my button

```
var btnbp1 = document.createElement('button');
btnbp1.value = '0';
btnbp1.setAttribute('onclick', 'selection()');
btnbp1.className = 'windowprimarybutton';
var btnBp1Img = document.createElement('img');
btnBp1Img.src= 'images/bp1.jpg';
btnbp1.appendChild(btnBp1Img);
divButtonsConteiner.appendChild(btnbp1);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVCgi.png)

Comment: you need to include [jquery](https://code.jquery.com)

Comment: @Eduardo Cruz Welcome to SO, Good practice at SO is giving exception as text, not as an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="btn" value="Mybtn">Click</button>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn").click(function () {

            var btnval = $(this).val();

            $('p').text(btnval);
        });
    });

</script>
```