# Console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my script code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js" defer></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
```

I try to create an ajax function, but it show some error in console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

How can I proceed?

Comment: Why have you included two jquery files??

Comment: where does the error shows ?

Comment: You included two JQuery CDN, remove one

Comment: @palaѕн i tried to delete one of that, but still got the same error.

Comment: @sh1hab in chrome F12 >> console

Comment: @TalhaF. still error sir

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file can't be found. Try to replace your code from your current code to this.

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still error sir

Comment: have you already removed this `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js" defer></script>`??

Comment: yes i already deleted that

Comment: Also, make sure to disable your cache

Comment: Try to remove `defer`. In addition, you can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: I already updated the script tag above. Try it again.

Comment: done, thanks all, refers to mart macion

Answer (score 0):

This error means your jQuery file has not been loaded. Based on your code, you have to remove one of the script tags that load the jQuery library. Then check that the path for loading jQuery is correct. You can do that by viewing the page source (in most browsers ctrl+u) and clicking on the script address and check if the file loads correctly.

Comment: the link is working perfectly, but still error