# I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html, web, error-handling, referenceerror

As a part of a register form, I am just checking if name is typed or empty.
Here's the HTML

```
<div class="text form-group justify-content-center mx-auto col-12">
     <input type="text" id="name" class=" " name="name" onkeyup='name_val();'>
    <label for="name"><span class="content">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name</span></label>
</div>
<p id="compare_name" class="text-center"> </p>
```

And here's the script.

```
var name_val = function (){
if($('#name').val() == ""){
    document.getElementById('compare_name').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('compare_name').innerHTML = 'This field can\'t be empty';
}
else{
    document.getElementById('compare_name').innerHTML = '';
}}
```

I have referenced jQuery on top of all scripts. But i still get this error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: name_val is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

I hope somebody could help me. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: How exactly did you "referenced jQuery on top of all scripts"?

Comment: @Pointy after the closing body tag, first script referenced was <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and then all other scripts

Comment: Well the problem is that either your jQuery import is not working, or that some other script is removing the global `$` binding. Without seeing more code it is impossible to provide any more help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this...

function name_val() {
...

// Content here...

...
}

I hope this will work...