# Countdown Status Bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was trying to build a clean countdown timer with a progress bar, I came up with this code I am not sure what seems to be the problem. I am pretty sure CSS is working all right and there has to be some problem with JavaScript.The countdown did not start instead I was left with just this bar[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c80U.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    #progressBar {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 10px auto;
      height: 22px;
      background-color: #0A5F44;
    }
    
    #progressBar div {
      height: 100%;
      text-align: right;
      padding: 0 10px;
      line-height: 22px;
      /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
      width: 0;
      background-color: #CBEA00;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Do not take in account */
    
    html {
      padding-top: 30px
    }
    
    a.solink {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      background: #f3f5f6;
      color: #cfd6d9;
      border: 1px solid #cfd6d9;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: all .3s;
      z-index: 999
    }
    
    a.solink::first-letter {
      text-transform: capitalize
    }
    
    a.solink:hover {
      color: #428bca
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<body>
  <script>
    function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
      var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
      $element.find('div').animate({
        width: progressBarWidth
      }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft / 60) + ":" + timeleft % 60);
      if (timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
      }
    };

    progress(600, 600, $('#progressBar'));
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What problem? Please describe what you are seeing, and what you expect. Are there any errors in the console? And `<script> src=...>` is an error.

Comment: Please do not repost the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63914001/countdown-progressive-bar) again - you can wait on your existing question to get some answer. - Also, your code works fine here you need to ensure that you are loading the scripts properly in your page `head`

Comment: would be great if you could create a js fiddle out of it or something so we can see the output

Comment: @Pranay try now - i have edited your snippet - its working fine - copy the exact same code.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Please do not fix code in the question; post an answer instead.

Comment: @KenY-N typo types question does not need an answers. Moving a div from bottom to top is not an answer - i suppose :)

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar Happy to help. You just need to move the div from bottom to the top after `</head>` to work it.

Comment: actually we have to define $ before using it and it is defined with jquery cdn so we have to add cdn before any script tag and also the script tag always use in bottom of body because it gives full access to upper html elements to jquery if we define it middle of elements it can create issue

Comment: @AlwaysHelping No, fixing code [is a Bad Edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/1270789).

Comment: @KenY-N Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63914001/countdown-progressive-bar) the other people have said and done the same thing but i guess OP did not get the point of having a div after the script to which i have explained. Any ways someone answered the same thing as well now below. Thanks :)

Comment: put the jquery import inside a head or body not out of them!!!

Answer (score 0):

I Think You Have Error In Many Things Like You Have To Add Jquery cdn Before script ,Error in Script tag ,And Also You Have to add html elements before script tag

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Do not take in account */
html{padding-top:30px}a.solink{position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;text-align:center;background:#f3f5f6;color:#cfd6d9;border:1px solid #cfd6d9;line-height:30px;text-decoration:none;transition:all .3s;z-index:999}a.solink::first-letter{text-transform:capitalize}a.solink:hover{color:#428bca}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft/60) + ":"+ timeleft%60);
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(6000, 6000, $('#progressBar'));
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Try This It Work Fine For Me

Answer (score 0):

I found different error, move the jquery import,  and add the function on document ready.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #progressBar {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 10px auto;
      height: 22px;
      background-color: #0A5F44;
    }
    
    #progressBar div {
      height: 100%;
      text-align: right;
      padding: 0 10px;
      line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
      width: 0;
      background-color: #CBEA00;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    /* Do not take in account */
    html{padding-top:30px}a.solink{position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;text-align:center;background:#f3f5f6;color:#cfd6d9;border:1px solid #cfd6d9;line-height:30px;text-decoration:none;transition:all .3s;z-index:999}a.solink::first-letter{text-transform:capitalize}a.solink:hover{color:#428bca}
    </style>
 <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <script>
    function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
        var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
        $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft/60) + ":"+ timeleft%60);
        if(timeleft > 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
    $(function() {
    progress(600, 600, $('#progressBar')); });

    </script>
   
    <div id="progressBar">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: why you add cdn to header it decrease speed of  page loading

Comment: The speed wasn't a requirement :)

Comment: It works really well, I had one doubt regarding the time what should I change if I want the time to be of different value. Thanks, ins advance.

Comment: You can change it  progress(6000, 6000, $('#progressBar'))  6000 = 100 minute or 60 = 1 minute –