# Why ajax call is not fetching data from Database (Laravel Project)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So the thing is when I click on the button, it will call an ajax function which will direct to controller file and store the data in **FollowupTreatment** variable, but in view file it isn't printing data and just print **N/A**

So here is the button

```
<tr>
      <th scope="row">
         <a role="button"
             style="text-decoration:underline;"
             data-toggle="modal"
             data-target="#summaryModal" onClick="fetchSummary({{$eachPatient->IdPatient}})">
           {{$eachPatient->IdPatient}}
         </a>
      </th>
</tr>
```

Here is the fetchsummary function

```
function fetchSummary(IdPatient){
         $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{{route('fetchSummary')}}",
             data:{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}","IdPatient" :IdPatient},
             success:function(response){
                 console.log(response);
                 $('#summaryModalBody').html(response);
             },
             error:function(error){
                 console.log(error);
             }
         });
}
```

Here is the route

```
    Route::post('/fetchSummary', [TreatmentController::class, 'fetchSummary'])->name('fetchSummary');
```

Here is the Treatmentcontroller class

```
public function fetchSummary(Request $request){
    
    $FollowupTreatment=DB::table("Treatment")
       ->join("Treatment_Followup","Treatment_Followup.treatmeant_id","Treatment.IdTreatment")
       ->join("Followup","Followup.IdFollowup","Treatment_Followup.follow_up")
       ->where('numerosettimana',4)
       ->where("Treatment.IdPatient",$request->IdPatient)
    
       ->get();

    return view('user_view.PatientTreatmentSummary',compact('FollowupTreatment'));
}
```

And Fianlly here is the View File (**PatientTreatmentSummary**)

```
<tr>
   <!-- complicanze minori=minor complications -->
   <th  class="table-info">Complicanze Minori</th>
      @for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
         <td class="data-{{$i+1}}">
            {{isset($FollowupTreatment[$i]->complicanzeminori) ? 
                   $FollowupTreatment[$i]->complicanzeminori   :
                   'N/A'}}
         </td>
      @endfor
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <!-- complicanze maggiori=major complications -->
    <th  class="table-info">Complicanze Maggiori</th>
       @for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
          <td class="data-{{$i+1}}">
             {{isset($FollowupTreatment[$i]->complicanzemaggiori) ?
                  $FollowupTreatment[$i]->complicanzemaggiori     :
                  'N/A'}}
           </td>
        @endfor
  </tr>
```

Here is the output of view file

[image]

It is showing this error in console

***Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at 1?_token=hJP8thspmb7DC9WTHnMWhWLtDHf74rLtrxivkWpZ&_method=get:25***

Comment: One of the cases might be:  jQuery not being loaded in the .blade.php file.

Comment: Maybe you have forgot to import jquery.
Reference: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: If jQuery is loaded in the blade template, try using `jQuery()` instead of `$()`

Comment: Tried but didn't worked :(

Comment: `dd($FollowupTreatment)` first check have any data?

Comment: Yes you are right, some data are missing in dd($FollowupTreatment) variable and maybe that is the reason it is printing N/A, but can you help me why the data is not coming in that variable??