# I want to change button's color when clicked with jquery code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change rating button's color when it is clicked. But JQuery code is not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C5dB.jpg)

```js
$(".vote").on("click",function(){
    alert("a");  //test
    $(this).css("backgroundColor","hsl(216, 12%, 54%)");
});
```

```html
<div class="rating">
  <button class="vote">1</button>
  <button class="vote">2</button>
  <button class="vote">3</button>
  <button class="vote">4</button>
  <button class="vote">5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: More importantly: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` (remember to include jQuery).

Comment: <script src="main.js"></script>     I included main.js file that jquery code exists

Comment: It works perfectly with jQuery: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/07sangkb/), so your attempted inclusion of jQuery appears to have failed, or you somehow forgot, or didn't clear/refresh the cached file that include(s|d) jQuery.

Comment: Now I added JQuery reference but still not working :'(

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

Comment: So what's different in your code that isn't in your question? What does `console.log($)` display in your browser console?

Comment: // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
  return new jQuery…

Comment: Im including JQuery like in this question's answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined. But still not working

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when JQuery is referenced.

```js
$(".vote").on("click",function(){
    alert("a");  //test
    $(this).css("backgroundColor","hsl(216, 12%, 54%)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating">
  <button class="vote">1</button>
  <button class="vote">2</button>
  <button class="vote">3</button>
  <button class="vote">4</button>
  <button class="vote">5</button>
</div>
```